# How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?

Tags: c, assembly, bit-manipulation, division, multiplication

How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?

Comment: Like you would do it on paper in middle school, only using binary instead of decimal.

Comment: @mtk: What is missing from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19780781/780717)? Are you looking for C or assembly implementation, particular operand widths, a specific division method (e.g. restoring vs non-restoring)?

Comment: Is subtraction OK?  All seems to be covered

Comment: What is the need behind this question? CPU's translate multiply and division operations into bitshifting and addition or subtraction already, and if that is if the compiler hasn't already done so.

Comment: @KellyS.French Just curiosity, it's more a way to imagine how a compiler can work with a restricted instruction set.

Comment: `imagine how a compiler can work with a restricted instruction set` the question would be better for letting this on. Then, there is _one operand known at compile time_, or even _both_.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To multiply in terms of adding and shifting you want to decompose one of the numbers by powers of two, like so:

```
21 * 5 = 10101_2 * 101_2             (Initial step)
       = 10101_2 * (1 * 2^2  +  0 * 2^1  +  1 * 2^0)
       = 10101_2 * 2^2 + 10101_2 * 2^0 
       = 10101_2 << 2 + 10101_2 << 0 (Decomposed)
       = 10101_2 * 4 + 10101_2 * 1
       = 10101_2 * 5
       = 21 * 5                      (Same as initial expression)
```

(`_2` means base 2)

As you can see, multiplication can be decomposed into adding and shifting and back again. This is also why multiplication takes longer than bit shifts or adding - it's O(n^2) rather than O(n) in the number of bits. Real computer systems (as opposed to theoretical computer systems) have a finite number of bits, so multiplication takes a constant multiple of time compared to addition and shifting. If I recall correctly, modern processors, if pipelined properly, can do multiplication just about as fast as addition, by messing with the utilization of the ALUs (arithmetic units) in the processor.

Comment: I know it was a while ago, but could you give an example with division? Thanks

Comment: I agree, this answer could do with some improvement, for while it gives a good answer for multiplication, it doesn't fully answer the question by omitting division

Answer (score 48):

[The answer by Andrew Toulouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777225/1182653) can be extended to division.

The division by integer constants is considered in details in the book "Hacker's Delight" by Henry S. Warren (ISBN 9780201914658).

The first idea for implementing division is to write the inverse value of the denominator in base two.

E.g.,
`1/3 = (base-2) 0.0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 .....`

So,
`a/3 = (a >> 2) + (a >> 4) + (a >> 6) + ...  + (a >> 30)`
for 32-bit arithmetics.

By combining the terms in an obvious manner we can reduce the number of operations:

`b = (a >> 2) + (a >> 4)`

`b += (b >> 4)`

`b += (b >> 8)`

`b += (b >> 16)`

There are more exciting ways to calculate division and remainders.

EDIT1:

If the OP means multiplication and division of arbitrary numbers, not the division by a constant number, then this thread might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699549/1182653

EDIT2:

One of the fastest ways to divide by integer constants is to exploit the modular arithmetics and Montgomery reduction: [What's the fastest way to divide an integer by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171301/whats-the-fastest-way-to-divide-an-integer-by-3?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks so much for the Hacker's Delight reference!

Comment: Ehm yes, this answer (division by constant) is only _partially_ correct. If you try to do '3/3' you'll end up with 0. In Hacker's Delight, they actually explain that there is an error that you have to compensate for. In this case: `b += r * 11 >> 5` with `r = a - q * 3`. Link: http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf page 2+.

Comment: It shoud be clarified that the answer's solution is not for general case division but for some special constant divisor cases e.g. **division by 3**, **division by 5** or **division by 7**. And the answer shows an example of **division by 3**. Check the *Hacker's Delight* book for more.

Answer (score 35):

X * 2 = 1 bit shift left
X / 2 = 1 bit shift right
X * 3 = shift left 1 bit and then add X

Comment: Do you mean `add X` for that last one?

Comment: It's still wrong - last line should read: "X * 3 = shift left 1 bit and then add X"

Comment: "X / 2 = 1 bit shift right", not entirely, it rounds down to infinity, rather than up to 0 (for negative numbers), which is the usual implementation of division (at least as far as I've seen).

Answer (score 32):

`x << k == x multiplied by 2 to the power of k`
`x >> k == x divided by 2 to the power of k`

You can use these shifts to do any multiplication operation. For example:

`x * 14 == x * 16 - x * 2 == (x << 4) - (x << 1)`
`x * 12 == x * 8 + x * 4 == (x << 3) + (x << 2)`

To divide a number by a non-power of two, I'm not aware of any easy way, unless you want to implement some low-level logic, use other binary operations and use some form of iteration.

Comment: @IVlad: How would you combine the above operations to perform, say, divide by 3 ?

Comment: @Paul R - true, that's harder. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: division by a constant is not too hard (multiply by magic constant and then divide by power of 2), but division by a variable is a little trickier.

Comment: shouldn't x * 14 == x * 16 - x * 2 == (x << 4) - (x << 2) really end up being (x<<4) - (x<<1) since x<<1 is multiplying by x by 2?

Answer (score 18):

1. A left shift by 1 position is analogous to multiplying by 2. A right shift is analogous to dividing by 2.
2. You can add in a loop to multiply. By picking the loop variable and the addition variable correctly, you can bound performance. Once you've explored that, you should use [Peasant Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Peasant_or_binary_multiplication)

Comment: +1:  But the left shift isn't just analogous to multiplying by 2.  It *is* multiplying by 2.  At least until overflow...

Comment: Shift-division yields incorrect results for negative numbers.

Answer (score 7):

A procedure for dividing integers that uses shifts and adds can be derived in straightforward fashion from decimal longhand division as taught in elementary school. The selection of each quotient digit is simplified, as the digit is either 0 and 1: if the current remainder is greater than or equal to the divisor, the least significant bit of the partial quotient is 1.

Just as with decimal longhand division, the digits of the dividend are considered from most significant to least significant, one digit at a time. This is easily accomplished by a left shift in binary division. Also, quotient bits are gathered by left shifting the current quotient bits by one position, then appending the new quotient bit.

In a classical arrangement, these two left shifts are combined into left shifting of one register pair. The upper half holds the current remainder, the lower half initial holds the dividend. As the dividend bits are transferred to the remainder register by left shift, the unused least significant bits of the lower half are used to accumulate the quotient bits.

Below is x86 assembly language and C implementations of this algorithm. This particular variant of a shift & add division is sometimes referred to as the "non-performing" variant, as the subtraction of the divisor from the current remainder is not performed unless the remainder is greater than or equal to the divisor (Otto Spaniol, "Computer Arithmetic: Logic and Design."  Chichester: Wiley 1981, p. 144). In C, there is no notion of the carry flag used by the assembly version in the register pair left shift. Instead, it is emulated, based on the observation that the result of an addition modulo 2<sup>n</sup> can be smaller that either addend only if there was a carry out.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define USE_ASM 0

#if USE_ASM
uint32_t bitwise_division (uint32_t dividend, uint32_t divisor)
{
    uint32_t quot;
    __asm {
        mov  eax, [dividend];// quot = dividend
        mov  ecx, [divisor]; // divisor
        mov  edx, 32;        // bits_left
        mov  ebx, 0;         // rem
    $div_loop:
        add  eax, eax;       // (rem:quot) << 1
        adc  ebx, ebx;       //  ...
        cmp  ebx, ecx;       // rem >= divisor ?
        jb  $quot_bit_is_0;  // if (rem < divisor)
    $quot_bit_is_1:          // 
        sub  ebx, ecx;       // rem = rem - divisor
        add  eax, 1;         // quot++
    $quot_bit_is_0:
        dec  edx;            // bits_left--
        jnz  $div_loop;      // while (bits_left)
        mov  [quot], eax;    // quot
    }            
    return quot;
}
#else
uint32_t bitwise_division (uint32_t dividend, uint32_t divisor)
{
    uint32_t quot, rem, t;
    int bits_left = CHAR_BIT * sizeof (uint32_t);

    quot = dividend;
    rem = 0;
    do {
            // (rem:quot) << 1
            t = quot;
            quot = quot + quot;
            rem = rem + rem + (quot < t);

            if (rem >= divisor) {
                rem = rem - divisor;
                quot = quot + 1;
            }
            bits_left--;
    } while (bits_left);
    return quot;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

I translated the Python code to C. The example given had a minor flaw. If the dividend value that took up all the 32 bits, the shift would fail. I just used 64-bit variables internally to work around the problem:

```
int No_divide(int nDivisor, int nDividend, int *nRemainder)
{
    int nQuotient = 0;
    int nPos = -1;
    unsigned long long ullDivisor = nDivisor;
    unsigned long long ullDividend = nDividend;

    while (ullDivisor <  ullDividend)
    {
        ullDivisor <<= 1;
        nPos ++;
    }

    ullDivisor >>= 1;

    while (nPos > -1)
    {
        if (ullDividend >= ullDivisor)
        {
            nQuotient += (1 << nPos);
            ullDividend -= ullDivisor;
        }

        ullDivisor >>= 1;
        nPos -= 1;
    }

    *nRemainder = (int) ullDividend;

    return nQuotient;
}
```

Comment: What about negative number? I tested -12345 with 10 using eclipse + CDT, but the result was not that good.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you do ```ullDivisor >>= 1``` before the ```while``` loop ? Also, won't ```nPos >= 0``` do the trick?

Comment: @kenmux You have to consider only the magnitude of the numbers involved, first, do the algorithm and then using some appropriate decision making statements, return the proper sign to the quotient/ remainder !

Comment: @VivekanandV You mean add the sign - later? Yes, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Take two numbers, lets say 9 and 10, write them as binary - 1001 and 1010.

Start with a result, R, of 0.

Take one of the numbers, 1010 in this case, we'll call it A, and shift it right by one bit, if you shift out a one, add the first number, we'll call it B, to R.

Now shift B left by one bit and repeat until all bits have been shifted out of A.

It's easier to see what's going on if you see it written out, this is the example:

```
      0
   0000      0
  10010      1
 000000      0
1001000      1
 ------
1011010
```

Comment: This seems fastest,  just requires a little extra coding to loop through the bits of the smallest number and compute the result.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-divide-two-numbers-using-only-bit-operations-in-Java).

This is only for division:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
        int partialSum, carry;
        do {
            partialSum = a ^ b;
            carry = (a & b) << 1;
            a = partialSum;
            b = carry;
        } while (carry != 0);
        return partialSum;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return add(a, add(~b, 1));
}

int division(int dividend, int divisor) {
        boolean negative = false;
        if ((dividend & (1 << 31)) == (1 << 31)) { // Check for signed bit
            negative = !negative;
            dividend = add(~dividend, 1);  // Negation
        }
        if ((divisor & (1 << 31)) == (1 << 31)) {
            negative = !negative;
            divisor = add(~divisor, 1);  // Negation
        }
        int quotient = 0;
        long r;
        for (int i = 30; i >= 0; i = subtract(i, 1)) {
            r = (divisor << i);
           // Left shift divisor until it's smaller than dividend
            if (r < Integer.MAX_VALUE && r >= 0) { // Avoid cases where comparison between long and int doesn't make sense
                if (r <= dividend) { 
                    quotient |= (1 << i);    
                    dividend = subtract(dividend, (int) r);
                }
            }
        }
        if (negative) {
            quotient = add(~quotient, 1);
        }
        return quotient;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for multiplication:

```
.data

.text
.globl  main

main:

# $4 * $5 = $2

    addi $4, $0, 0x9
    addi $5, $0, 0x6

    add  $2, $0, $0 # initialize product to zero

Loop:   
    beq  $5, $0, Exit # if multiplier is 0,terminate loop
    andi $3, $5, 1 # mask out the 0th bit in multiplier
    beq  $3, $0, Shift # if the bit is 0, skip add
    addu $2, $2, $4 # add (shifted) multiplicand to product

Shift: 
    sll $4, $4, 1 # shift up the multiplicand 1 bit
    srl $5, $5, 1 # shift down the multiplier 1 bit
    j Loop # go for next  

Exit: #


EXIT: 
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: It is MIPS assembly, if this is what you are asking. I think I used MARS to write/run it.

Answer (score 1):

The below method is the implementation of binary divide considering both numbers are positive. If subtraction is a concern we can implement that as well using binary operators.

#### Code

```
-(int)binaryDivide:(int)numerator with:(int)denominator
{
    if (numerator == 0 || denominator == 1) {
        return numerator;
    }

    if (denominator == 0) {

        #ifdef DEBUG
            NSAssert(denominator==0, @"denominator should be greater then 0");
        #endif
        return INFINITY;
    }

    // if (numerator <0) {
    //     numerator = abs(numerator);
    // }

    int maxBitDenom = [self getMaxBit:denominator];
    int maxBitNumerator = [self getMaxBit:numerator];
    int msbNumber = [self getMSB:maxBitDenom ofNumber:numerator];

    int qoutient = 0;

    int subResult = 0;

    int remainingBits = maxBitNumerator-maxBitDenom;

    if (msbNumber >= denominator) {
        qoutient |=1;
        subResult = msbNumber - denominator;
    }
    else {
        subResult = msbNumber;
    }

    while (remainingBits > 0) {
        int msbBit = (numerator & (1 << (remainingBits-1)))>0?1:0;
        subResult = (subResult << 1) | msbBit;
        if(subResult >= denominator) {
            subResult = subResult - denominator;
            qoutient= (qoutient << 1) | 1;
        }
        else{
            qoutient = qoutient << 1;
        }
        remainingBits--;

    }
    return qoutient;
}

-(int)getMaxBit:(int)inputNumber
{
    int maxBit = 0;
    BOOL isMaxBitSet = NO;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(inputNumber)*8; i++) {
        if (inputNumber & (1<<i)) {
            maxBit = i;
            isMaxBitSet=YES;
        }
    }
    if (isMaxBitSet) {
        maxBit+=1;
    }
    return maxBit;
}


-(int)getMSB:(int)bits ofNumber:(int)number
{
    int numbeMaxBit = [self getMaxBit:number];
    return number >> (numbeMaxBit - bits);
}
```

For multiplication:

```
-(int)multiplyNumber:(int)num1 withNumber:(int)num2
{
    int mulResult = 0;
    int ithBit;

    BOOL isNegativeSign = (num1<0 && num2>0) || (num1>0 && num2<0);
    num1 = abs(num1);
    num2 = abs(num2);


    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(num2)*8; i++)
    {
        ithBit =  num2 & (1<<i);
        if (ithBit>0) {
            mulResult += (num1 << i);
        }

    }

    if (isNegativeSign) {
        mulResult =  ((~mulResult)+1);
    }

    return mulResult;
}
```

Comment: What is this syntax? `-(int)multiplyNumber:(int)num1 withNumber:(int)num2`?

Answer (score 1):

it is basically multiplying and dividing with the base power 2

shift left = x * 2 ^ y

shift right = x / 2 ^ y

shl eax,2  = 2 * 2 ^ 2 = 8

shr eax,3  = 2 / 2 ^ 3 = 1/4

Comment: `eax` can't hold a fractional value like `1/4`.   (Unless you're using fixed-point instead of integer, but you didn't specify that)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a 16-bit x86 solution, there is a piece of code by **JasonKnight** here[1](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/73569-multiply-two-variables-without-using-mul-function/) (he also includes a signed multiply piece, which I haven't tested). However, that code has issues with large inputs, where the "add bx,bx" part would overflow.

The fixed version:

```
softwareMultiply:
;    INPUT  CX,BX
;   OUTPUT  DX:AX - 32 bits
; CLOBBERS  BX,CX,DI
    xor   ax,ax     ; cheap way to zero a reg
    mov   dx,ax     ; 1 clock faster than xor
    mov   di,cx
    or    di,bx     ; cheap way to test for zero on both regs
    jz    @done
    mov   di,ax     ; DI used for reg,reg adc
@loop:
    shr   cx,1      ; divide by two, bottom bit moved to carry flag
    jnc   @skipAddToResult
    add   ax,bx
    adc   dx,di     ; reg,reg is faster than reg,imm16
@skipAddToResult:
    add   bx,bx     ; faster than shift or mul
    adc   di,di
    or    cx,cx     ; fast zero check
    jnz   @loop
@done:
    ret
```

Or the same in GCC inline assembly:

```
asm("mov $0,%%ax\n\t"
    "mov $0,%%dx\n\t"
    "mov %%cx,%%di\n\t"
    "or %%bx,%%di\n\t"
    "jz done\n\t"
    "mov %%ax,%%di\n\t"
    "loop:\n\t"
    "shr $1,%%cx\n\t"
    "jnc skipAddToResult\n\t"
    "add %%bx,%%ax\n\t"
    "adc %%di,%%dx\n\t"
    "skipAddToResult:\n\t"
    "add %%bx,%%bx\n\t"
    "adc %%di,%%di\n\t"
    "or %%cx,%%cx\n\t"
    "jnz loop\n\t"
    "done:\n\t"
    : "=d" (dx), "=a" (ax)
    : "b" (bx), "c" (cx)
    : "ecx", "edi"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert some* multiplication/division statements to bit shift operations using the formulae:

```
x * y = x << log2(y)
x / y = x >> log2(y)
```

* Assuming `y` is a power of 2

Examples:

```
4 * 16    = 4 << 4
2000 / 4  = 2000 >> 2
288 / 32  = 288 >> 5
```

Comment: Multiple existing answers point this out.  For right shift, that's only true for unsigned, or non-negative signed integers; `x >> log2(y)` rounds towards -Infinity, assuming it's an arithmetic right shift at all, but `x / y` rounds towards zero in C.

Answer (score 0):

So to get the bits required for the variable divide requires a divide itself.

its the msb/DIVIDER - is the bits of the powers required for the shifting of the divide,  and it ends being a chicken and egg problem.

Its a bit strange but->

If you multiply all the other numbers of your system, you've essentially divided that one number compared to the rest.

then just shift the whole system back if you got any zero padding at the lsb's.

Thats if u cant stand the division method with the condition in it, if theres only less than 5 numbers to your equation your running its not too bad to do, but I know its not the best solution yet... but i'll keep thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. https://gist.github.com/swguru/5219592

```
import sys
# implement divide operation without using built-in divide operator
def divAndMod_slow(y,x, debug=0):
    r = 0
    while y >= x:
            r += 1
            y -= x
    return r,y 


# implement divide operation without using built-in divide operator
def divAndMod(y,x, debug=0):

    ## find the highest position of positive bit of the ratio
    pos = -1
    while y >= x:
            pos += 1
            x <<= 1
    x >>= 1
    if debug: print "y=%d, x=%d, pos=%d" % (y,x,pos)

    if pos == -1:
            return 0, y

    r = 0
    while pos >= 0:
            if y >= x:
                    r += (1 << pos)                        
                    y -= x                
            if debug: print "y=%d, x=%d, r=%d, pos=%d" % (y,x,r,pos)

            x >>= 1
            pos -= 1

    return r, y


if __name__ =="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        y = int(sys.argv[1])
        x = int(sys.argv[2])
     else:
            y = 313271356
            x = 7

print "=== Slow Version ...."
res = divAndMod_slow( y, x)
print "%d = %d * %d + %d" % (y, x, res[0], res[1])

print "=== Fast Version ...."
res = divAndMod( y, x, debug=1)
print "%d = %d * %d + %d" % (y, x, res[0], res[1])
```

Comment: This looks like python. The question was asked for assembly and/or C.