# How do I divide two integers without using the division operator?

Tags: c++

compsci novice here. I am supposed to program 2 user inputted values and have them multiplied and divided without using the * and / operators.

I have figured out how to multiply but not divide...

```
    //Multiplication
    cin >> digit1;
    cin >> digit2;

    float product = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < digit2; i++) product = product + digit1;
    cout << product << endl;

    return 0;
```

as for division I'm not exactly sure...

```
    cin >> digit1;
    cin >> digit2;

    float quotient = 0;

    //Enter Division operation
    cout << quotient << endl;
    return 0;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `digit1 * (digit2 ^ -1)` perhaps.

Comment: You could solve this in a very similar fashion to how you solved the multiplication one.  If multiplication is just rapid addition, what is division?  Instead of computing a product though, think of going to zero and counting iterations.

Comment: @MattBall hmm, I'm not sure I'm allowed to use the ^ operator...

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5387432/314291

Comment: @pstrjds I think I know what you are saying, can you perhaps elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Moojave - What is the [quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient) in a division problem? "The number of times the divisor divides into the dividend". So you need to count the number of times you can put the divisor into the dividend.  Follow a pattern similar to your multiplication solution.

Comment: Obviously the OP isn't allowed to use the '/' operator either even though he states the % operator in the question.

Comment: @trumpetlicks where did I state the % operator?

Comment: @Moojave - Look at the 1st sentence of your own question!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks Oh! Terribly sorry, my bad! I edited it...

Comment: @Moojave - Knew what you meant :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division without using '/'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386377/division-without-using)

Answer (score 3):

For divide, one could do something like this (below would be digit2 / digit1):

```
int movingNum = 0;
int i = 0;
while(movingNum < digit2){
    // This is the counter of how many times digit1 goes into digit2, increment it
    // because the running sum is still less than digit2
    i++;

    // increment the moving sum by digit1 so that it is larger by digit1 moving through
    // the next iteration of the loop
    movingNum += digit1;
}

cout << "digit1 goes into digit2 " << i << " times.";
```

For digit1 / digit2:

```
int movingNum = 0;
int i = 0;
while(movingNum < digit1){
    // This is the counter of how many times digit2 goes into digit1, increment it
    // because the running sum is still less than digit1
    i++;

    // increment the moving sum by digit2 so that it is larger by digit2 moving through
    // the next iteration of the loop
    movingNum += digit2;
}

cout << "digit2 goes into digit1 " << i << " times.";
```

These are obviously for integer divide, if the two inputs do not divide equally, then there will be a remainder.  This remainder can be calculated after the above loop by:

```
int remainder = movingNum - digit2;
```

If you are truly looking for a floating point answer / result, this would be an entirely different answer.

Comment: It does not work for me, I keep getting the output as 0

Comment: @Moojave  is digit1 greater than digit2???  If it is than the answer SHOULD be 0.  Is the requirement to have digit1 / digit2, or digit2 / digit1???  Multiplying is easy, dividing requires an understanding of order!

Comment: I was hoping to lead OP to this without stating it although I was thinking of using subtraction in my loop and looping while > 0.  Using the increasing sum you get an easy way to compute the remainder though.

Comment: I made a mistake actually, I don't need the % modulus at all. My bad, I just need to divide 2 numbers where I cannot use /

Comment: @pstrjds - I like moving forward in the loop because it allows for the (what looks to be unsigned divide) actual result to be ~2x the capable result of a true int.  I didn't want to confuse the OP with unsigned int versus regular int however.  If indeed his numerics are all positive, than moving forward will allow him to find results that are on the order of 2x the size of a true int versus an unsigned.

Comment: @Moojave - Have you tried the 2nd code portion of my answer?

Comment: @trumpetlicks yes, I inputted 40 and 8, and I got the output as 4 instead of 5...

Comment: @Moojave - I will edit, I think that movingNum needs to be initialized to 0 instead of digit2!

Answer (score 3):

Division is repeated 
subtraction.

Example: 4 / 2 literally means, how many 2s constitute 4 (which is, quotient).
So, subtract the dividend by divisor until dividend becomes zero while keeping a count of the number of times you're subtracting divisor(here, 2) from dividend(here, 4).

Try this code (This is not for floating point answers. If that is what you want, let me know! :D).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int divi, divs, quo = 0, rem = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &divi, &divs);

    for(rem = divi - divs; rem >= 0; rem = rem-divs) {

        if(rem < 0)                         // to ensure that the right answer is obtained when the divisor isn't a factor of dividend.
          break;
        else
          quo++;
  }

printf("%d\n", quo);

return 0;
```

}