# Divide a number by 5 without using division operator

Tags: c, algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [implement division with bit wise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284898/implement-division-with-bit-wise-operator)
>   [Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694546/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators)

I came across this question in an interview. I want to know if there any possibly way to divide a number by 5 without using division operator and if any possible solution exists using bitwise operators only.I figured one out using repeated subtraction till zero approaches. Number can be signed and unsigned. 
Please suggest any way out without using +,-,/,* and %.

Comment: What format is the "number" ? 2s complement integer ? Floating point ? BCD ? Other ?

Comment: Consider the format to be in decimal format

Comment: the following question contains solution for deviding by 3. It could help you to find the equivalent for 5 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694546/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators

Comment: Wait what do you want to do with the remainder?  I.e. 14/5 equals what?

Comment: [Divisiblity of 5 without using % and / operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17113660/995714)

Comment: the other duplicates are for dividing by general cases and by 3. This should be reopened. [MS has explained about the divide by 5 case here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devdev/2005/12/12/integer-division-by-constants/)

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to just multiply by 0.2 (but I don't know a solution for how to implement that using bitwise operators from the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

Simply reduce division to subtracting one number from the other until you reach zero :D

```
int number = 25;
int divisor = 5;
int result = 0;
while((number-divisor)>=0){
  result++;
  number = number - divisor;
}
```

Comment: but subtraction is not allowed too

Comment: @Omkant - I don't believe subtraction has been precluded.  Admittedly, though, this algorithm will be slow for large n.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a way out from this link which seems to provide an answer to my question.
http://codegambler.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/division-operation-without-using-division-operator/

Comment: That code uses addition and subtraction though: `quotient+=division(p-q,divisor);`

Comment: @Kevin glad you pointed it out. I must have specified a proper algorithm in my question. My mistake.