# Truncate last X digits of number without division by 10eX

Tags: php, time, blocking, usleep

I'm making a blocking algorithm, and I just realised that adding a timeout to such algorithm is not so easy if it should remain precise.
Adding timeout means, that the blocking algorithm should abort after X ms if not earlier. Now I seem to have two options:

1. Iterating time (has mistake, but is fast)

- Check blocking condition
- Iterate `time_elapsed` by 1 (which means 1e-6 sec with use of [usleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php))
- Compare `time_elapsed` with `timeout`. (**here is the problem I will talk about**)
- `usleep(1)`

2. Getting system time every iteration (slow, but precise)

- I **know how to do this**, please do not post any answers about that.

###Compating `timeout` with `time_elapsed`###
And here is what bothers me. The `timeout` will be in milliseconds (10e-3) while `usleep` sleeps for 10e-6 seconds. So my `time_elapsed` will be 1000 times more precise than `timeout`. I want to **truncate** last three digits of `time_elapsed` (operation equal to `floor($time_elapsed/1000)` without dividing it. Division algorithm is too slow.
###Summary###
I want to make my variable 1000 times smaller without dividing it by 1000. I want just get rid of the data. In binary I'd use bit-shift operator, but have no idea how to apply it on decimal system.

###Code sample:###
Sometimes, when people on SO cannot answer the theoretical question, they really hunger for the code. Here it is:

```
floor($time_elapsed/1000);
```

I want to replace this code with something much faster. Please note that though the question itself is full of timeouts, the question title is **only about truncating that data**. Other users may find the solution useful for other purposes than timing.

Comment: Can se see your code so far?

Comment: Don't you understand the explanation? My code strictly follows steps in point `1.` of my solution list. Only thing that matters is the `floor($time_elapsed/1000)` which I need to be replaced by a faster calculation.

Comment: No, I don't fully understand your explanation. Posting the code you have tried would help. Why not just do everything in milliseconds?

Comment: Added the code with a bit of irony. Please stick to the question title. The solution may serve to various purposes.

Comment: No need to be snarky. Your explanation may not be as clear as you think it is. Look it up yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284898/implement-division-with-bit-wise-operator

Comment: Incidentally, I wanted the code you tried for the bit-shifting. Not the useless `floor()` code that you don't want to use.

Comment: the division takes 0,000006 microseconds..you really need to optimize that?

Comment: @showdev: I do not have it. My question is about how should such code look like (and why).

Comment: @redreggae The checking algorithm altogether turned 10 sec timeout to 10.9. Do not forget that there are **thousands** of iterations. That turns 0.000006 to 0.6 in a swift.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help [Php number format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Though this does cause rounding, if that is unacceptable then I don't think its possible because PHP is loosely typed that you cant define numbers with a particular level of precision.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this solution is even slower. When you compare string operations to number operations you are comparing bullet to hour hand on clock.

Comment: Then the absolute last thing I can think of is rounding, after this I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(int)($time_elapsed*0.001)
```

this should be a lot faster