# How to divide by 9 using just shifts/add/sub?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, cpu-architecture, integer-arithmetic

Last week I was in an interview and there was a test like this:

Calculate `N/9` (given that `N` is a positive integer), using only
**SHIFT LEFT, SHIFT RIGHT, ADD, SUBSTRACT** instructions.

Comment: Can `N` be negative?  If so, is the right-shift an arithmetic shift or logical shift?

Comment: [Divide by 10 using bit shifts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5558492/995714), [Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/995714), [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2776211/995714), [Implement division with bit-wise operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5284898/995714)

Comment: to divide by 9, [multiply by 954437177](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm)

Comment: @templatetypedef: your deleted answer is nearly right, but the pattern repeats every 6 bits, not every 4 bits.  With `L=(1/16+1/32+1/64)`,  you get a very close approximation to 1/9 from `L + L/2^6 + L/2^12 + L/2^18 + L/2^24 + L/2^30 == ~0.11111111110949423164`.  I just made an edit to fix it, so you should undelete it.  I was fumbling around with sums of power-of-two fractions, and would probably have gotten to your answer at some point, but I don't want to type it up since you've already done so.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code actually doesn't work, unfortunately, because all the divisions round down. If you try it on a value like 9 / 9, for example, you get 0 rather than the expected 1.

Comment: @templatetypedef: ahh, I see.  Is there a workaround like adding `1` to the initial value before any shifting?  hrm, no it's not that easy.  Maybe add 1 to the highest bit-position that will be shifted out, to do a divide with rounding instead of truncation?  (So it's like adding `0.5` to non-truncated fixed-point result of the shift, except you actually do it before the shift.)

Comment: (Without conditional operations, the "obvious" way to divide is multiply by inverse, as linked in Lưu Vĩnh Phúc's second comment.)

Comment: can you use `for` loops and `if`s?  you can encode binary division with single `for` loop using `<<,>>,+,-,if (a<b)`. Slow naive division `a/9=c` is even easier: `for (c=0;a>=9;a-=9) c++;`

Comment: @Tracy added answer on 32bit arithmetics valid for inputs up to `147455` including. No loops, using just `+,-,<<,>>`

Comment: Given the nature of the answers and the attempts at one, this doesn't look like it's a fair interview question at all. I wonder if the question was supposed to be multiply by 9, which is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

first, find the representation of 1/9 in binary
0,0001110001110001
means it's (1/16) + (1/32) + (1/64) + (1/1024) + (1/2048) + (1/4096) + (1/65536)
so **(x/9)** equals **(x>>4) + (x>>5) + (x>>6) + (x>>10) + (x>>11)+ (x>>12)+ (x>>16)**

Possible optimization (if loops are allowed):
if you loop over 0001110001110001b right shifting it each loop, 
add "x" to your result register whenever the carry was set on this shift
and shift your result right each time afterwards,
your result is x/9

```
        mov cx, 16     ; assuming 16 bit registers
        mov bx, 7281   ; bit mask of 2^16 * (1/9)
        mov ax, 8166   ; sample value, (1/9 of it is 907)
        mov dx, 0      ; dx holds the result

    div9:
        inc ax         ; or "add ax,1" if inc's not allowed :) 
                       ; workaround for the fact that 7/64 
                       ; are a bit less than 1/9
        shr bx,1
        jnc no_add
        add dx,ax
    no_add:
        shr dx,1
        dec cx
        jnz div9
```

( currently cannot test this, may be wrong)

Comment: you are using loops and conditional jumps which @Tracy has still not approved. In current state of OP they are not to be used.

Comment: See my comment on the question about templatetypedef's deleted answer, and his/her reply:  The flaw in  `(1/16) + (1/32) + ...` is that integer division always rounds down.

Comment: @PeterCordes when dividing by 9, adding 5 to the dividend n prior of division would be "rounding" up (ok, it's 0.5555 not 0.5) ... the (1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 + ...) approach seems only wrong on n where n is a multiple of 9, so adding 1 to n should work (before dividing, that is)

Answer (score 1):

1. **you can use fixed point math trick.**

   so you just scale up so the significant fraction part goes to integer range, do the fractional math operation you need and scale back.

   ```
   a/9 = ((a*10000)/9)/10000
   ```

   as you can see I scaled by `10000`. Now the integer part of `10000/9=1111` is big enough so I can write:

   ```
   a/9 = ~a*1111/10000
   ```
2. **power of 2 scale**

   If you use power of 2 scale then you need just to use bit-shift instead of division. You need to compromise between precision and input value range. I empirically found that on `32 bit` arithmetics the best scale for this is `1<<18` so:

   ```
   (((a+1)<<18)/9)>>18 = ~a/9;
   ```

   The `(a+1)` corrects the rounding errors back to the right range.
3. **Hardcoded multiplication**

   Rewrite the multiplication constant to binary

   ```
   q = (1<<18)/9 = 29127 = 0111 0001 1100 0111 bin
   ```

   Now if you need to compute `c=(a*q)` use hard-coded binary multiplication: for each `1` of the `q` you can add `a<<(position_of_1)` to the `c`. If you see something like `111` you can rewrite it to `1000-1` minimizing the number of operations.

   If you put all of this together you should got something like this **C++** code of mine:

   ```
   DWORD div9(DWORD a)
       {
       // ((a+1)*q)>>18 = (((a+1)<<18)/9)>>18 = ~a/9;
       // q = (1<<18)/9 = 29127 = 0111 0001 1100 0111 bin
       // valid for a = < 0 , 147455 >
       DWORD c;
       c =(a<< 3)-(a    ); // c= a*29127
       c+=(a<< 9)-(a<< 6);
       c+=(a<<15)-(a<<12);
       c+=29127;           // c= (a+1)*29127
       c>>=18;             // c= ((a+1)*29127)>>18
       return c;
       }
   ```

   Now if you see the binary form the pattern `111000` is repeating so yu can further improve the code a bit:

   ```
   DWORD div9(DWORD a)
       {
       DWORD c;
       c =(a<<3)-a;        // first pattern
       c+=(c<<6)+(c<<12);  // and the other 2...
       c+=29127;           
       c>>=18;             
       return c;
       }
   ```