# C++ calculator without operators

Tags: c++

I need to make a C++ calculator that can +, -, *, /, % and ^.  I cannot use  +, -, *, /, and % in my code at all.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
ll add(ll a,ll b){ 
    if(b==0)return a;
    else return add(a^b,(a&b)<<1);
}
ll sub(ll a,ll b){ 
    if(b==0)return a;
    else return sub(a^b,((~a)&b)<<1);
}
```

Here is what I have.  I don't know how to code the multiplication and division parts.  Any help?

Comment: looks like homework,  please review the question rules and try to ask an specific problem rather asking help for a general issue.

Comment: A simple google search results in many questions like this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284898/implement-division-with-bit-wise-operator

Comment: Please don't use macros like `ll`.

Comment: May I know why?

Comment: First, macros are to be used sparingly.  Second, why obfuscate something as obvious as `long long`?  Third, `ll` looks like `11`.  Fourth, the code becomes harder to understand.  Fifth, you want to get a job as a programmer?

Comment: Wow that seems harsh!  HAHA.  Anyways Im i kid, and I dont think I would mistake it for 11.

Comment: Re: "harsh" -- yes, a bit, but that's a bad habit to get into. If you do it now you'll have to unlearn it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ll mul(ll a,ll b){ 
    if(b<0){
        b=add(~b,1);
        a=add(~a,1);
    }
    ll res=0;
    while(b>0){
        if(b&1)res=add(res,a);
        a<<=1;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}
ll div(ll a,ll b){
    ll c=0,op=0;
    if(a<0){
        a=add(~a,1);
        op^=1;
    }
    if(b<0){
        b=add(~b,1);
        op^=1;
    }
    if(b!=0){
        while(a>=b){
            a=sub(a,b);
            c=add(c,1);
        }
    }
    if(op)c=add(~c,1);
    return c;
}
```

Following your code format, I hope this solution helps! 
Here, I make use of the add and subtract to do the multiply and divide, using more bitwise operators ( &, |, ^, ~, <<, >> ) . You could also refer to cplusplus.com to read more about them.  So in this case you can see then in multiplication, I shift the bits to the left, so it is sort of like moving the ones place to the tens place, etc.  If you need further clarifications, feel free to seek help. :)

Comment: Recommend a bit of care in how you answer homework and homework-esque questions. Homework answers should be light on code and heavy on explanation because if you simply hand off a ball of code, all the asker is likely to get from it is slightly improved skill at cutting and pasting. The end result is often [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and no one benefits from that. [Except maybe Cthulhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu).