# Quick alternatives to floating point multiplication to calculate percentages

Tags: performance, arduino, heuristics, integer-division, integer-arithmetic

I'm writing some code on an Arduino that needs to run fast and make rough approximations to percentages of integers.

For example, given a number I want to find 90% of it, or 70% or 30% etc. The obvious way to do it is multiply by a floating point eg. x * 0.9; or x * 0.3; But because I need speed, I want to avoid a floating point calculation. If I was just dividing by a power of two, I'd do a bitwise shift, but are there similar techniques for approximating 90%, 80% etc. using integers?

Answer (score 5):

You can approximate those percentages with fractions that have a power-of-two denominator.

Here's a simple example with `2^16`:

```
90% = 90 / 100 ~ 58982 / 65536
70% = 70 / 100 ~ 45875 / 65536
30% = 30 / 100 ~ 19661 / 65536

 x% =  x / 100 ~ x * 655 / 65536
```

The divisions (which are now powers-of-two) can be done with shifts.

Of course, it may take some pre-computation to generate those fractions.

Comment: Ah ... that looks promising.

So x% of y is (y * x * 655 / 65536) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `2^16` should be accurate enough. If you need more precision you can always use something larger than `2^16`.

Comment: You also try `(y * x * 655 + 32768) / 65536` if you want it to round better.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shifting  [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-with-only-using-bit-shifting-and-adding)

You can use bit shifting for to multiply and divide arx example x = (x*9)/10

As for a code example,  if you get stuck I could try and burn some brain cells to work it out.
Just ask :)