# bitwise operation(s) to truncate the last two digits of a number

Tags: c++, debugging, math, bit-manipulation

I have an integer `n`, and I'd like to truncate the last two digits of the number using only bitwise operations.

So, in regular arithmetic, it'd be as simple as `n /= 100`. But how would this be done with bitwise operation(s)?

Thanks,

(This is in c++, by the way)

[Edit]: For instance, given the number `1234`, I'd like to get `12`. (truncate the last two digits `34`)

[Edit2:] Let me rephrase the question. I'm trying to understand why a particular function that's supposed to truncate the last two digits of a number kind of screws things up when given a negative input. (And I don't have the code for this function)

**Here's the set of inputs and their corresponding outputs**

-200901 ==> 186113241

-200801 ==> 186113242

-200701 ==> 186113243

-200601 ==> 186113244

-190001 ==> 186113350

-190101 ==> 186113349

-190201 ==> 186113348

-190301 ==> 186113347

Comment: So are are you trying to turn the number 1234 into the number 12? Or trying to get the number 34 out of the number 1234? Or trying to turn 1234 into 1200? (I think you are trying to turn it into 12, but want to make sure).

Comment: 1234 ===> 12 is what I'm trying to do

Comment: What's wrong with `n /= 100`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're trying to do this?  Is this just for fun?

Comment: Yeah, fun. and for bug tracing. (I'm dealing with some bug, and I suspect the person who wrote the code use bitwise ops. So I'd like to know if this is what they did)

Comment: only bitwise operations ? no addition ?, no if ? no loop of any kind ?

Comment: @npe: No this is not homework. (It's summer! Gah! I'm trying not to think of the  school~! :P )

Comment: Ok, here's the thing. Given this number `200901`, the function would return `2009` because it's supposed to truncate the last two digits, but if I give it `-200901`, it'd return `186113241`. So I'm trying to find out, if the bug is due to the fact that its owner wasn't aware of the sign when doing the shifting or whatever it is that he did to truncate the number.

Comment: Bitwise operations work on powers of two.  Working on powers of ten is going to be difficult, awkward, or possibly downright impossible.

Comment: Well, ok. Then does anyone happen to have any idea what might've been done to produce the weird result that I posted in my comment above?

Comment: Why do you think the code in question is using bitwise operations?  Maybe it is doing character operations and that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Uhm, the function takes an input of integer, so if the code isn't using bitwise or regular maths operations, what else could it be using? (Character operations  seem slow. And I'm pretty sure that performance is guaranteed for this function)

Comment: @OneTwoThree can your test this function on more numbers? And give it's output.

Comment: Can't you simply show us the code of that function that's causing you trouble?

Comment: @Daan If I had access to the code, I wouldn't be asking for an answer~!

Comment: @OneTwoThree if it's java you always can decompile it and see source code

Comment: Uhm, I was wrong. It's in C++, not java.

Comment: In that case you'll have to do as @Nikita suggested and give us some more examples of how this mysterious function works...

Comment: Sure! I'll update the question with input and output.

Comment: Ok! I have updated my question with some explanation as to why I'm doing this kind of stuff. :) and some input/outputs

Comment: @OneTwoThree can you try minimal int: -2147483648 ?

Comment: Anyone have the slightest idea/suspect what might be the problem? :)

Comment: Not yet :( What is the result for -1 and -100 ? :)

Comment: `-1 ==> 186115250` and `-100 ==> 186115249`

Comment: This looks like it has a pattern. And the number `186xxxxxx` looks suspiciously familiar. I'm trying to remember where I've seen it before.

Comment: @OneTwoThree What is the result of the function for 0, 1 and 100?

Comment: These comments are getting long. Consider using the [chat] link to move the conversation to chat. When you start a chat, it automatically imports the comments to the chat so you don't lose any of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to divide by a constant : 100

Following [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-with-only-using-bit-shifting-and-adding)  that was given by Suraj Chandran in his comments,

You can re-interpret this as a multiplication by 1/100.

In base 2, 
    1/100 can be approximated to 
      1/2^7 * ( 1/2^0 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^6+ 1/2^7+ 1/2^8+ 1/2^9 +
      1/2^11+ 1/2^13+ 1/2^14+ 1/2^15+ 1/2^20+ 1/2^22 + 1/2^26 + 1/2^27 + 1/2^28 1/2^29)

so you have and approximation with
    (n >> 0 + n >> 2 + n >> 6 + n >> 7 + n >> 8 + n >> 9 +
    n >> 11 + n >> 13 + n >> 14 + n >> 15 + n >> 20 + n >> 22 + n >> 26 + n >> 27 + n >> 28 + n >> 29) >> 7

Is this more or less what you have in your legacy code ?

I wouldn't dare saying that this will always give you the correct answer as I have done no scrutiny on the effects of the approximations here and there may very well be rounding issues in some cases.

In java code that would be

remaining = (( n>>0 ) + (n >> 2) + (n >> 6) + (n >> 7) + (n >> 8) + (n >> 9) + (n >> 11) + (n >> 13) + (n >> 14) + (n >> 15) + (n >> 20) + (n >> 22) + (n >> 26) + (n >> 27) + (n >> 28) + (n >> 29)) >> 7;

added an example on http://ideone.com/8UlD7

I coulnd't find a way to replace the additions by bitwise operations + could not reproduce the results you have with your negative values

Comment: I don't know. Really. I don't have access to the code. But if this'd produce the same output for the negative cases I listed, then I guess you're right~ :)

Comment: Well, sorry, just to clarify. So this in Java code would be: `n = n >> 7 ^ n >> 9 ^ n >> 13 ^ n >> 14 ^ n >> 15 ^ n >> 16 ^n >> 18 ^ n >> 20 ^ n >> 21 ^ n >> 22 ^ n >> 27 ^ n >> 29;` ? I tried that and always got 1976 as the output no matter what the value of n was initialized to

Comment: modified my answer with a java example. Still looking into xor and your negative corner cases

Comment: Your code always give a number that is 1 unit less than the correct result. So for instance `200901 ===>[your function] ===> 2008`, but it's supposed to be `2009`

Comment: yes. not always. you can try with 12345 for example. These are rounding issues. for example, for 200901 => 257150 / 128 => 2008.98 ; A scrutiny for rounding issues would be necessary on my solution. In any case I can't reproduce the results you have with negative values. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, another approach.

```
1234 : 100 = 12, remainder 34
```

Now in binary, I hope I didn't mess it up:

```
 100 1101 0010 : 110 0100 = 1100 Result
- 11 0010 0
-----------
   1 1011 00
  -1 1001 00
  ----------
     0010 001
    -       0
    ---------
      010 0010
     -       0
     ---------
       10 0010 remaining
```

Have fun converting that to an algorithm. It will be slow as hell compared to `x /= 100`, no matter how you do it.