# Performing bit division without arithmetic operators

Tags: c, assembly, bit-manipulation, division

I am trying to complete an assignment that requires me to write three functions for binary arithmetic. badd() was provided for me, so I used it to help write the bsub() and bmult() functions. I am having trouble understanding how I should perform the bdiv() function, however. I know I need to iterate through the bits using a right shift and my bsubb() function, but I don't know how to implement it. Below are the functions that I have written so far. Let me know if you notice any mistakes that I made in writing them(meaning bsub() and bmult()). Thanks.

```
/** This function adds the two arguments using bitwise operators. Your      
* implementation should not use arithmetic operators except for loop
* control. Integers are 32 bits long.  This function prints a message
* saying "Overflow occurred\n" if a two's complement overflow occurs
* during the addition process. The sum is returned as the value of
* the function.
*/
int badd(int x,int y){

int i;

char sum;
char car_in=0;
char car_out;
char a,b;

unsigned int mask=0x00000001;
int result=0;

for(i=0;i<32;i++){

  a=(x&mask)!=0;
  b=(y&mask)!=0;
  car_out=car_in & (a|b) |a&b;
  sum=a^b^car_in;

  if(sum) {
     result|=mask;
  }

  if(i!=31) {
     car_in=car_out;
  } else {
     if(car_in!=car_out) {
 printf("Overflow occurred\n");
     }
  }

  mask<<=1;
}

 return result;
 }

// subracts two integers by finding the compliemnt
// of "y", adding 1, and using the badd() function
// to add "-y" and "x"
int bsub(int x, int y){

return badd(x, badd(~y, 1));
}


//add x to total for however many y
int bmult(int x,int y){

int total;
int i;
for(i=0; i < = y; i++)
{
 total = badd(total,x)
}
 return total;
}

// comment me
unsigned int bdiv(unsigned int dividend, unsigned int divisor){

// write me
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have to combine multiplication and substraction to calculate both the quotient and the reminder, by solving [this simple equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder)

Comment: According to [homework guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), this question is too contrived to be a practical programming question and should be closed as Not a Real Question.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question [performing arithmetic operations in binary using only bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538724/performing-arithmetic-operations-in-binary-using-only-bitwise-operators).

Answer (score 5):

Not much to say here, it's just some basic math in base-2:

```
unsigned int bmult(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    int total = 0;
    int i;

    /* if the i-th bit is non-zero, add 'x' to total */
    /* Multiple total by 2 each step */
    for(i = 32 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        total <<= 1;
        if( (y & (1 << i)) >> i )
        {
            total = badd(total, x);
        }
    }

    return total;
}

unsigned int bdiv(unsigned int dividend, unsigned int divisor)
{
    int i, quotient = 0, remainder = 0;

    if(divisor == 0) { printf("div by zero\n"); return 0; }

    for(i = 31 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        quotient <<= 1;
        remainder <<= 1;
        remainder |= (dividend & (1 << i)) >> i;

        if(remainder >= divisor)
        {
            remainder = bsub(remainder, divisor);
            quotient |= 1;
        }
    }

    return quotient;
}
```

These two articles are enough to code these samples: [Div](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29) and [Mul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochanski_multiplication).

Answer (score 2):

In the code that follows I implement addition and subtraction using the same idea as in the question. The only practical difference is that in my implementation these two functions also take in a carry-in/borrow-in bit and produce a carry-out/borrow-out bit.

The carry-in bit is used to implement subtraction via addition and this bit helps to get correct values of the carry-out and borrow-out bits. Basically, I implement typical CPU-like addition and subtraction with the carry flag in the status register.

The carry/borrow bits are then used to implement comparison via subtraction. I implement comparison without the `>=` operator, which I also consider arithmetic, because of its not quite bit-wise nature. The comparison function is needed in the division function because of using the [restoring division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Restoring_division).

I also avoid using the `!` operator and use `^1` instead.

The division function takes the divisor as 2 `unsigned ints`, the most- and the least-significant parts of it. At the end it replaces the most-significant part with the remainder and the least-significant part with the quotient. So, it does both division and modulo and does them in a typical CPU-like way (e.g. like the x86 `DIV` instruction). The function returns 1 on success and 0 on overflow/division by 0.

The main function does a simple test. It compares the results from the division function against the results of direct division and terminates with an error message on a mismatch.

I use `unsigned long long` in the test part to be able to test divisor=`UINT_MAX` without falling into an infinite loop. It may take too much time to test the entire range of values of the dividend and the divisor, which is why I cap them at 0xFFFF and 0xFF respectively instead of at `UINT_MAX`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned add(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned carryIn, unsigned* carryOut)
{
  unsigned sum = a ^ b ^ carryIn;
  unsigned carryOuts = a & b | (a | b) & carryIn;
  *carryOut = 0;
  if (sum & (carryOuts << 1))
    sum = add(sum, carryOuts << 1, 0, carryOut);
  else
    sum |= carryOuts << 1;
  *carryOut |= (carryOuts & (UINT_MAX / 2 + 1)) >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1); // +-*/ are OK in constants
  return sum;
}

unsigned sub(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned borrowIn, unsigned* borrowOut)
{
  unsigned diff = add(a, ~b, borrowIn ^ 1, borrowOut);
  *borrowOut ^= 1;
  return diff;
}

unsigned less(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  unsigned borrowOut;
  sub(a, b, 0, &borrowOut);
  return borrowOut;
}

int udiv(unsigned* dividendh, unsigned* dividendl, unsigned divisor)
{
  int i;
  unsigned tmp;

  if (less(*dividendh, divisor) ^ 1/* *dividendh >= divisor */)
    return 0; // overflow

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
  {
    if (less(*dividendh, UINT_MAX / 2 + 1) ^ 1/* *dividendh >= 0x80...00 */)
    {
      *dividendh = (*dividendh << 1) | (*dividendl >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
      *dividendl <<= 1;

      *dividendh = sub(*dividendh, divisor, 0, &tmp);/* *dividendh -= divisor; */
      *dividendl |= 1;
    }
    else
    {
      *dividendh = (*dividendh << 1) | (*dividendl >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
      *dividendl <<= 1;

      if (less(*dividendh, divisor) ^ 1/* *dividendh >= divisor */)
      {
        *dividendh = sub(*dividendh, divisor, 0, &tmp);/* *dividendh -= divisor; */
        *dividendl |= 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int udiv2(unsigned* dividendh, unsigned* dividendl, unsigned divisor)
{
  unsigned long long dividend =
    ((unsigned long long)*dividendh << (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT)) | *dividendl;

  if (*dividendh >= divisor)
    return 0; // overflow

  *dividendl = (unsigned)(dividend / divisor);
  *dividendh = (unsigned)(dividend % divisor);

  return 1;
}


int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long dividend, divisor;

  for (dividend = 0; dividend <= /*UINT_MAX*/0xFFFF; dividend++)
    for (divisor = 0; divisor <= /*UINT_MAX*/0xFF; divisor++)
    {
      unsigned divh = 0, divl = (unsigned)dividend, divr = (unsigned)divisor;
      unsigned divh2 = 0, divl2 = (unsigned)dividend;

      printf("0x%08X/0x%08X=", divl, divr);

      if (udiv(&divh, &divl, divr))
        printf("0x%08X.0x%08X", divl, divh);
      else
        printf("ovf");

      printf(" ");

      if (udiv2(&divh2, &divl2, divr))
        printf("0x%08X.0x%08X", divl2, divh2);
      else
        printf("ovf");

      if ((divl != divl2) || (divh != divh2))
      {
        printf(" err");
        return -1;
      }

      printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. while dividend < divisor 
   add zero after decimal point in quotient
   and shift right dividend by 1
2. Now check if the number of bits in divisor is equal to number of bits in dividend 
   if not, shift divisor left until number of bits in dividend are equal to number of bits    in  divisor.
3. Now subtract dividend, divisor
   and add 1 to quotient, make sure you have 1 to the quotient at right place (Like decimal position)

Repeat the process until dividend is either 0 or 1