# C function: multiply 2 numbers using bit twiddling?

Tags: c

I need some help answering the above question Any twiddling idea?

Comment: Are both numbers just any numbers unknown in advance? The question *could* make sense for the opposite case, e.g. if one of the numbers is constant.

Comment: [Been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12697523/968261).

Comment: Just 2 simple integers unsigned.

Comment: for example multiply 2 unsiged integers using only shift right and shift left.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get a lot more here: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Answer (score 3):

Treat one of the inputs as a bitmask. For each bit in it that is set, you want to add the other input, shifted that many spaces left, to your result. This assumes unsigned inputs: non-2's-complement signed inputs require special treatment of the sign bit.

I think I can safely predict that this will be less efficient than the CPU's built-in multiply operation.