# Improved binary division algorithm in MIPS

Tags: mips, division, integer-arithmetic

The concept of binary division in MIPS has been explained in the Pattern's computer organization book. However, when I comes to the improved division algorithm, things are not very clear. Consider the following diagram.

[image]

While it is talking about 32-bit integers, I want to know what are the register sizes for `1001010÷1000`? Here is my understanding:

Dividend: `1001010` which should be 8-bit `0100,1010`

Divisor: `1000` which should be 8-bit `0000,1000`

Now what about the registers in the diagram? Divisor 32-bit should be 8-bit and big 64-bit remainder register should be 16-bit. Am I right?

Now the problem is, where to put the divisor's value in the register? Higher left or lower left since we will shift it to right, it should be initialized as `1000,0000`.

Also, the big remainder register is shifted left as the caption states but it also has a shift right control input.

Can someone explains this diagram with a working example?

Comment: This seems to be a question about hardware, rather than programming, and thus off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: If that becomes clear then we are able to program it with MIPS assembly language. So, in my opinion, it not completely off-topic

Comment: I would suggest revising the question so it is clearly focused on programming. If the question is mostly about combining the quotient and remainder in a double-width register (typically register *pair* for software), take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32443307/780717)