# 8086 Assembly SHR instruction dividing by 3 problem

Tags: assembly, masm, bit-shift, emu8086, integer-division

I know how shr division works but it dividing just even numbers. I want to divide the number by 3. What is the assembly 8086 code of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can't use a right shift alone to divide by anything but a power of 2.

Comment: You can use `div` as an easy (but slow) way to divide by arbitrary numbers, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi for how to do it with multiplication, similar to dratenik's answer but using `mul`.

Comment: A faster algorithm that's inaccurate only for large numbers is also possible, see [Divide by 10 using bit shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558492).  Also, [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443307) shows how to use *only* shifts and add/adc (not mul with a magic constant) in a loop to do division.

Comment: A binary bit-shift by design implies a multiplication (or division) by a power of 2. For 8086 your best bet would be the `div` instruction, see https://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_grp.htm

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by 3 is the same as multiplying by 1/3. 1/3 in binary is 0.010101...

So in pseudocode:

```
sum:=0
tmp:=IN
while (tmp>0) {
  shr tmp, 2
  sum += tmp
}
OUT:=sum
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but not too accurate: from 1 to 500 this gets 19 correct answers; it is usually under by 1.

Comment: [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443307) shows how to properly do exact division with just right shifting (and add/adc), for runtime-variable divisors.  If you want to optimize that for a known constant 3, that might be a good starting point.