# Calculate percentage of a number

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the percentage of a given number, for example, if I wanted to know what is 80% of 100. The answer would be 80.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
percentage = 80
x = 100

y = percentage * x
decimal = percentage / 100

final = decimal * x

print(final)
```

Output: `80.0`

What would be the better alternatives?

Comment: Better in what respect?

Comment: What's wrong with what you did? You can shorten it to `final = percentage/100 * x`

Comment: My code seems to be lengthy, so I wanted to look for better alternatives to do it in a more simpler and efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your equation looked correct

```
def percentage_of(num, of_num):
    return (num / of_num) * 100

print(percentage_of(50, 100))
```

find 80 is what percentage of 100

```
def percentage(num, per):
    return (num * per) / 100


print(percentage(100, 80))
80
print(percentage(101,77))
77.77
```

I built a function as a better alternative.  you may be able to bit shift to get more efficiency for divide

[How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding)

Comment: How is this a "better alternative"?

Comment: This seems to be a function that takes two numbers and find what percentage one is of the other, rather than taking a number and a percentage and finding that percentage of the number.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as `final = (percentage/100)*x`. This is shorter and eliminates the extra variable `y`, which isn't a very informative variable name. Also, putting parentheses around `percentage/100` both means that you don't have to worry about what Python's order of operations is, and makes it clearer to anyone reading your code why you're dividing by 100 (i.e., it's because you're dealing with percentages).