# ArmV7 simulation using cpulator

Tags: assembly, armv7, seven-segment-display, risc

if i want to print the value in seven segment display like 12. how can I do that?. i am currently working on cpulator armv7 mode. help will be appreciated.

.text
.equ sevendisplay, 0xff200020
.global _start
_start:

ldr r0, =sevendisplay    @ Load the address of the seven-segment display
mov r1, #12     //THIS THE REGISTER WITH VALUE

```
ldr r2, [r0]    //Load the current value from the display
and r2, r2, #0b0000000000000000 // two seven segment display 
orr r2, r2, r1  //Combine with the new value
str r2,[r0]
```

stop:
mov r7,#1
swi 0
.end

Comment: AND with `0b0000000000000000` clears all the bits, like `mov r2, #0`.  After breaking an integer down into decimal digits (with repeated division by 10), you could use a lookup table of 7-segment bit-patterns.  (ARM with NEON SIMD can do that in parallel with vtbl, but the division part is still serial.)

Comment: now i understand!! I need to break down the number "12" into "1" and "2" by repetitive sub by 10 and then do the bitwise operation. thank you sir.

Comment: ARM has `udiv` and `sdiv` instructions you can use.  (Some cores may lack those). Repetitive subtraction is a terrible division algorithm for numbers that aren't tiny, I wouldn't recommend it; testing with a number like 12345678 could take multiple seconds in an emulator with repeated-subtraction.  Without hardware `udiv`, using bit-shifting and add/sub takes O(log n) time.  [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443307) shows C  (and x86 asm) for it.

Comment: sir, in my version there is no udiv and sdiv instruction (need repetitive subtraction)  that's why I was struggling. i have successfully solved my problem using repetitive subtraction. And  i am agree with that "Repetitive subtraction is a terrible division algorithm." But i am bound to do that only this way.

Comment: Ok, yeah, some ARM cores don't have hardware division.  But like I said in the last part of my last comment, there's an O(log(n)) algorithm that involves shifting, not just subtraction.  That's what production code would typically use on CPUs without hardware division.  But for a beginner exercise where efficiency isn't necessary (or maybe when numbers are small and small code-size is more important), repeated subtraction is fine if it's not too slow for testing.