# What's the fastest algorithm to divide an integer by 3 without using a division instruction?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the fastest way to divide an integer by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171301/whats-the-fastest-way-to-divide-an-integer-by-3)

Assume the dividend fits into a single word of memory, and that you can use all standard instructions besides division.

Comment: Add this one to the annals of stupid interview questions.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, though it's related.  The other question asked if it's possible to divide by 3 faster without using the division operator than with using it.  The accepted answer is that it's not.  Neither the question nor that answer duplicates this question.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that question in my original search. Multiplying by 0x55555556 seems to be the way to go. It seems to be equivalent to multiplying by the binary representation of 1/3, rounded up so that you get the correct answer when the dividend is divisible by 3.