# Multiply or divide in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arithmetic-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use multiplication or division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226465/should-i-use-multiplication-or-division)

Poking around in some (C++) 3D library I often see code like this:

```
float fInvLength = 1.0f / fLength;
rkAxis.x = x * fInvLength;
rkAxis.y = y * fInvLength;
rkAxis.z = z * fInvLength;
```

Is this really faster than this code:

```
rkAxis.x = x / fLength;
rkAxis.y = y / fLength;
rkAxis.z = z / fLength;
```

I'm primarily interested in C#/.NET performance but I don't mind some info about C++ as well.

Comment: Altough the duplicate is primarily for Python. Maybe you find this also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053810/c-xna-multiplication-faster-than-division

Comment: I remember implementing multiply and divide in asm on CPU that didn't have these computation unit. Divide did take more time to compute, but on modern hardware I really doubt that. Mayby in some very tight loop.

Comment: I created a benchmark testing this code before it was closed. In my test (which does each section (as written) 1000000 times) the first method was faster (`00:00:00.0094078` versus `00:00:00.0222377`). As you can see, the difference is negligible; and would depend on machine and compiler.