# How much cycles math functions take on modern processors

Tags: c, math, gcc, assembly, x86-64

We know that modern processors execute instructions such as `cosine` and `sin` directly on the processor as they have opcodes for it. My question is how much cycles these instructions normally take. Do they take constant time or depend upon input parameters?

Comment: Some compilers produce, either for optimization reasons or for simplicity, calls to `cos` or `sin` routines. These routines may be assembly coded or in plain C, and may use or not the processor math instructions. And these instructions could be slower than their software routine counterparts. Current super-scalar out of order processors don't have a well defined number of cycles per instruction.

Comment: Also, different CPUs will have different timings for these instructions due to differences in architecture.  "Best practice" for a normal programmer is to just assume that calling the standard math library function will give you the best performance (these libraries will be heavily optimized) - but if you're into the nitty-gritty, check out Agner Fog's very comprehensive [Instruction Timing Charts](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).  Cheers!

Comment: Why are you asking??? Why does that matter to you?? Other aspects should also matter to you (conformance to standards, accuracy of computed results, ...). Are you coding a compiler??

Comment: `fsin` (and family) are rarely used nowadays. Especially on x64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Talking about "cycles for an instruction" for modern processors got to be difficult quite a while ago.  Processors these days contain multiple execution cores, their operation can overlap and can execute out-of-order.

A good example of the essential consideration is given in the Intel processor manual, volume 4, appendix C.  It breaks down instruction timing by Latency and Throughput.  Latency is the number of cycles an execution core requires to complete a micro-op.  Throughput is the number of cycles required to have the execution unit accept the same instruction again.  Throughput is generally *lower* than Latency, including having fractional values in the table.  A side-effect of having more than one execution unit of the same type.  The type is important, that tells you whether instructions can overlap.

Maybe you got the essential message here: it greatly depends what *other* instructions surround the code you are interested in timing.  Those other instructions may well execute concurrently with the expensive one.  At which point they take, effectively, 0 cycles.  Or they may not, stalling the pipeline because the execution unit is busy with a previous instruction.  The kind of details that programmers that write code optimizers care a lot about.

Some sample data from the manual, picking the most modern core in the tables:

- FMUL, latency = 7, throughput = 2, FP_MUL execution unit
- FDIV, latency = 6, throughput = 5, unspecified unit
- FSQRT, latency = 38, throughput = 43, FP_DIV exeution unit
- FSIN, latency = 160-180, throughput = 130, unspecified unit

A much better bang on SIMD instructions.

The only meaningful thing to do is *measure*, not assume.

Comment: What micro architecture was this for?

Comment: Ok well I can't find it (only as P4 (not Core), which fits the fmul and fsin latencies and throughput and fits the fsqrt throughput but not its latency). I can't make sense of the latency/throughput for fdiv though - how does that *ever* get a lower latency than a multiplication? And that fsqrt with a lower latency than throughput - the DIV unit gets tired and must rest 5 cycles..?

Comment: @harold: maybe FSQRT needs 38 cycles of the FP_DIV unit and 5 cycles in custom logic, reorganizing the result.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think you meant _reciprocal of the throughput_ instead of _throughput_.

Comment: @harold: also note that Agner Fog lists FSQRT latency in PIV as 43, and says elsewhere that Intel doesn't include the full latency in its tables, listing some latencies (e.g: moving data between execution units) in "general latencies" instead of in the instruction itself.

Answer (score 15):

The times vary depending on the processor model. Times typically range from tens of CPU cycles to a hundred or more.

(The times consumed by many instructions vary depending on circumstances, because instructions use a variety of resources in the processor [dispatcher, execution units, rename registers, and more], so how long an instruction delays other work depends on what else is going on in the processor. For example, if some code is doing almost entirely load and store instructions, then a very occasional sine instruction might not slow its execution at all. However, instructions that take tens of CPU cycles are usually dominated by their times in the execution unit, which is the part that does the actual numerical calculation.)

The execution times may vary depending on input parameters. Large arguments to trigonometric functions must be reduced modulo 2π, which is a complicated problem by itself.

In the Mac OS X math library, we generally write our own implementations, often in assembly language, for various reasons that may include speed, conformance to standards, suitability for the application binary interface, and other features.

If you are just curious, then “tens to hundreds of processor cycles” may be a good enough answer, especially without specifying a particular processor model. Essentially, the time is long enough that you should not use these operations without good reason. (E.g., I have seen code that obtains π as 4·arctan(1). Do not do that.)

If you have other reasons for asking, you should explain, so that answers can be focused.