# How to evaluate computational complexity of a function?

Tags: python, c#, math

I've got a bunch of functions that I can use, and they are used many times per second. I would like to know how to evaluate which functions affect my calculation times the most.

How could I go about it?

I'm trying to find out specifically how demanding is:

[image]

compared to other commonly used functions such as SquareRoot(X), cube of (x), sigmoid etc?

Comment: Are you trying to test, which mathematical function gives you the best performance?

Comment: The usual mathematical functions are implemented in hardware/firmware in the processor and appear as single opcodes. The processor manufacturer documents the running time of these functions, which can depend on the value of the argument, and processor load. It is usually better to use these intrinsic functions rather than derived ones. Your example calls for a hyperbolic sine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12335361/1196549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, most mathematical functions like that would be evaluated in constant time. This simply means that there is a finite number of instructions used, regardless of the value of the input parameter.  Often by a single instruction, but sometimes by a short loop.

The computational complexity says nothing about the actual time to evaluate the function, only how it would grow with the input parameter. So if you want to measure the actual performance you need to do actual measurements.

Usually when discussing computational complexity it is assumed that the values fit in whatever data-type is used, i.e. you would not need to handle arbitrary precision math.

As a rule of thumb, simple instructions, like addition or multiplication are single digit number of cycles, things like division in the lower double digits, and some 'complex' instructions like trigonometry can go up to three digits. 'slow' in this context would still be measured in nanoseconds, so still very fast unless you need to compute it millions of times.

Comment: I've run tests on that, measuring times for 15k iterations on each functions, and the values are very close. The difference could very well be the result of other processing. 
Even the function above seems to be calculated in nearly the same time as any other. 
To my surprise identity function wasn't the fastest.

Comment: @lj h Benchmarking can be tricky. On .Net the gold standard is to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html). I have no idea regarding Python, but I would assume it to be more difficult to get accurate numbers it is often interpreted.

Comment: All the functions I tried scored about 1iteration per millisecond. 
The slowest were approx 0.87 iterations per millisecond for squareRoot, but most of them were between 0.94-0.97 it/ms, so really close. 
I'm surprised cubic root was much faster than square root.

Comment: I used C# and unity to measure delta.Time for all iterations for each function. 
I've done it a bunch of times for between 1000 to 30000 iterations for every function and the results were very consistent.

Comment: @lj h if you are measuring 1 iteration per millisecond you are not measuring the actual runtime of the instructions, but something else. The correct approach is to use BenchmarkDotNet, or in a pinch, a stopwarch over a large amount of iterations. By `delta.Time` I would assume you are running unity3D, and that would be completely inappropriate way to measure runtime of a function.