# How to check if an integer can be divided by 3

Tags: java

How to check if my integer can be divided by 3 as below:

```
for(int i=0; i<24;  i++){
   //here, how to check if "i" can be divided by 3 completely(e.g. 3, 6, 15)?

}
```

Comment: You have about 20 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you could ask clearer questions or follow up on answers so they can be accepted.

Comment: This question seems pretty clear to me. It's asking how to divide the current number in the loop by 3 and got no remainder.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the modulo operator.

```
if(i % 3 == 0)
```

Also see [Modulo operation at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a loop, you can use the fact that every third number can be divided by 3.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 24;  i += 3) {
   System.out.println(i + " can be divided by 3");
   System.out.println((i+1) + " cannot be divided by 3");
   System.out.println((i+2) + " cannnot be divided by 3");
}
```

This avoids the need for a modulo and cuts the number of loops by a factor of 3.

Answer (score 6):

Use the MOD operator

```
for(int i=0; i<24;  i++){
   if( i%3 == 0 )
       // It is divisible by 3

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, what you *could* do (it *might* be a bit faster; it is faster on my machine) is:

```
boolean canBeDevidedBy3 = ((int) (i * 0x55555556L >> 30) & 3) == 0;
```

instead of

```
boolean canBeDevidedBy3 = (i % 3) == 0;
```

However, the multiplication trick only works for `-2 <= i <= 1610612735`. This answer was inspired by [this optimization question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171301/whats-the-fastest-way-to-divide-an-integer-by-3). But if I can give you a tip: use `(i % 3) == 0`. It's so much simpler, and will always work.

Answer (score 4):

Check the remainder of i devided by 3

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the loop:

```
if (i%3 == 0)
    // it can be divided by 3
```

`%` is called "mod" or "modulus" and gives you the remainder when dividing two numbers.

These are all true:

```
6 % 3 == 0
7 % 3 == 1
7 % 4 == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( i % 3 == 0 )
```

The % operator delivers you the rest of the division i / 3

Answer (score 0):

```
if( i % 3 == 0 ){
System.out.println("can be divided by 3");
}else{
System.out.println("cant divide by 3");
}
```

Is this question for real?