# Efficient (bit-wise) division by 24

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Coding for an embedded platform with no integer divisor (nor multiplier), is there a quick way to perform a 'divide by 24'?

Multiply by 24 is simply

```
int a;
int b = (a << 4) + (a << 3); // a*16 + a*8
```

But division? It's a really simple divisor, with only two bits set?

Comment: [Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/995714), http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the result to be bit-exact, then you could consider multiplying by 1/24:

```
uint16_t a = ...;

uint32_t b = (uint32_t)a * (65536L / 24);

uint16_t c = b / 65536;
```

Of course, if your platform doesn't have a hardware multiplier, then you will need to optimise that multiplication.  As it turns out, (65536 / 24) is approximately equal to 2730, which is 101010101010 in binary.  So that multiply can be achieved with 3 shifts and adds.

Comment: 3 shifts and adds.. sorry for being such a newbie (trying to outperform a C18 compiler..) - how do you multiply by 2730 in 3 shifts and adds? I've tested on python that ((a/8)*683)/2048 is good enough for my purposes, and doesn't overflow 16bit for the range of 'a' that interest me, now just shoving it into bit operations.

Comment: @qdot: As you can see from the binary representation, 2730 = 10 * 273 = (8 + 2) * (256 + 16 + 1) (so actually four shifts and three adds).

Comment: yeah. That was exactly what I've been missing fron the '3 shifts and adds'. Anyways, I got the compiler to help me out with efficient multiply, now the whole hand-tuned 576-choice switch statement is down from 180us to 21us. Not too bad for a 6MIPS core.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you can use the fact that `24=8*3`, so you can divide by `8` using shifting once again: `a / 8 == a >> 3`. Afterwards you have to divide the result by `3`. A discussion about how to do that efficiently can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171301/whats-the-fastest-way-to-divide-an-integer-by-3). Of course if you are coding in `c` (or any other higher level language really), it might be worthwile to simply look at the compileroutput first, it is possible that the compiler already has some tricks for this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coding in C. No, the compiler just calls a helper long division function for a 'divide by 3', so no joy there. The 0xAAAB trick is great, see my comment above.