# bitwise division rounding to nearest zero

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation

I want to perform an signed integer bitwise division by a power of 2. However, I encounter several problem. I just wonder if anyone can help me.

First, I try to use bit shifting alone:

```
int result = number >> n;
```

However, I got a problem when I try to divide a negative number. (it always round with a number with bigger magnitude. example: -9/4=-3 instead of -2. So, I look this problem in the internet, that end me up with this solution:

```
int result = (number + (1<<n)-1) >> n;
```

However, when I try 11/4 = 3 instead of 2

Any suggestions? I can only use ! ~ & ^ | + << >> (no loop or if/switch allowed)

Comment: its not clear for me. 1) are you using `/` to obtain the result **or** 2)using `>>` to perform the equivalent division?

Comment: @Koushik, He says he can use only these operators: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>. Also, no loops or if conditions/switches.

Comment: @Koushik i'm calling a function div(11,2) to perform 11/4

Comment: @AnishRam i just wanted to make sure he dint leave out `/`. now its clear to me.

Comment: A helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694546/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method is bad because it relies on:

- right shifts of negative integers being arithmetic shifts (may not be the case)
- signed integers being in the 2's complement representation (extremely rarely may not be the case)
- integers not having any padding bits (these days on modern CPUs you won't find padding bits, although the standard allows their existence)

And it may cause undefined behavior on some dividends (e.g. `INT_MIN`) due to signed integer overflow.

Therefore it isn't portable and isn't guaranteed to work always. You have been warned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int DivByShifting1(int n, unsigned shift)
{
  int sgn = n >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
  return ((((n + sgn) ^ sgn) >> shift) + sgn) ^ sgn;
}

int main(void)
{
  int n, s;
  for (n = -10; n <= 10; n++)
    for (s = 0; s <= 4; s++)
      printf("%d / %d = %d\n", n, 1 << s, DivByShifting1(n, s));
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/vJt4nJ)):

```
-10 / 1 = -10
-10 / 2 = -5
-10 / 4 = -2
-10 / 8 = -1
-10 / 16 = 0
-9 / 1 = -9
-9 / 2 = -4
-9 / 4 = -2
-9 / 8 = -1
-9 / 16 = 0
-8 / 1 = -8
-8 / 2 = -4
-8 / 4 = -2
-8 / 8 = -1
-8 / 16 = 0
-7 / 1 = -7
-7 / 2 = -3
-7 / 4 = -1
-7 / 8 = 0
-7 / 16 = 0
-6 / 1 = -6
-6 / 2 = -3
-6 / 4 = -1
-6 / 8 = 0
-6 / 16 = 0
-5 / 1 = -5
-5 / 2 = -2
-5 / 4 = -1
-5 / 8 = 0
-5 / 16 = 0
-4 / 1 = -4
-4 / 2 = -2
-4 / 4 = -1
-4 / 8 = 0
-4 / 16 = 0
-3 / 1 = -3
-3 / 2 = -1
-3 / 4 = 0
-3 / 8 = 0
-3 / 16 = 0
-2 / 1 = -2
-2 / 2 = -1
-2 / 4 = 0
-2 / 8 = 0
-2 / 16 = 0
-1 / 1 = -1
-1 / 2 = 0
-1 / 4 = 0
-1 / 8 = 0
-1 / 16 = 0
0 / 1 = 0
0 / 2 = 0
0 / 4 = 0
0 / 8 = 0
0 / 16 = 0
1 / 1 = 1
1 / 2 = 0
1 / 4 = 0
1 / 8 = 0
1 / 16 = 0
2 / 1 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
2 / 4 = 0
2 / 8 = 0
2 / 16 = 0
3 / 1 = 3
3 / 2 = 1
3 / 4 = 0
3 / 8 = 0
3 / 16 = 0
4 / 1 = 4
4 / 2 = 2
4 / 4 = 1
4 / 8 = 0
4 / 16 = 0
5 / 1 = 5
5 / 2 = 2
5 / 4 = 1
5 / 8 = 0
5 / 16 = 0
6 / 1 = 6
6 / 2 = 3
6 / 4 = 1
6 / 8 = 0
6 / 16 = 0
7 / 1 = 7
7 / 2 = 3
7 / 4 = 1
7 / 8 = 0
7 / 16 = 0
8 / 1 = 8
8 / 2 = 4
8 / 4 = 2
8 / 8 = 1
8 / 16 = 0
9 / 1 = 9
9 / 2 = 4
9 / 4 = 2
9 / 8 = 1
9 / 16 = 0
10 / 1 = 10
10 / 2 = 5
10 / 4 = 2
10 / 8 = 1
10 / 16 = 0
```

Note that `((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)` is a compile-time constant and therefore `*` and `-` can be allowed.

Another version, which is very similar, but does not require right shifts of negative integers to be arithmetic shifts and is free of signed integer overflow (2's complement-ness and padding bits are still limitations, but virtually in-existent in today's practice):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int DivByShifting2(int n, unsigned shift)
{
  unsigned un = n;
  unsigned sgn = 1 + ~(un >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1));
  un = ((((un + sgn) ^ sgn) >> shift) + sgn) ^ sgn;
  memcpy(&n, &un, sizeof n);
  return n;
}

int main(void)
{
  int n, s;
  for (n = -10; n <= 10; n++)
    for (s = 0; s <= 4; s++)
      printf("%d / %d = %d\n", n, 1 << s, DivByShifting2(n, s));
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/bVNWaV)):

```
-10 / 1 = -10
-10 / 2 = -5
-10 / 4 = -2
-10 / 8 = -1
-10 / 16 = 0
-9 / 1 = -9
-9 / 2 = -4
-9 / 4 = -2
-9 / 8 = -1
-9 / 16 = 0
-8 / 1 = -8
-8 / 2 = -4
-8 / 4 = -2
-8 / 8 = -1
-8 / 16 = 0
-7 / 1 = -7
-7 / 2 = -3
-7 / 4 = -1
-7 / 8 = 0
-7 / 16 = 0
-6 / 1 = -6
-6 / 2 = -3
-6 / 4 = -1
-6 / 8 = 0
-6 / 16 = 0
-5 / 1 = -5
-5 / 2 = -2
-5 / 4 = -1
-5 / 8 = 0
-5 / 16 = 0
-4 / 1 = -4
-4 / 2 = -2
-4 / 4 = -1
-4 / 8 = 0
-4 / 16 = 0
-3 / 1 = -3
-3 / 2 = -1
-3 / 4 = 0
-3 / 8 = 0
-3 / 16 = 0
-2 / 1 = -2
-2 / 2 = -1
-2 / 4 = 0
-2 / 8 = 0
-2 / 16 = 0
-1 / 1 = -1
-1 / 2 = 0
-1 / 4 = 0
-1 / 8 = 0
-1 / 16 = 0
0 / 1 = 0
0 / 2 = 0
0 / 4 = 0
0 / 8 = 0
0 / 16 = 0
1 / 1 = 1
1 / 2 = 0
1 / 4 = 0
1 / 8 = 0
1 / 16 = 0
2 / 1 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
2 / 4 = 0
2 / 8 = 0
2 / 16 = 0
3 / 1 = 3
3 / 2 = 1
3 / 4 = 0
3 / 8 = 0
3 / 16 = 0
4 / 1 = 4
4 / 2 = 2
4 / 4 = 1
4 / 8 = 0
4 / 16 = 0
5 / 1 = 5
5 / 2 = 2
5 / 4 = 1
5 / 8 = 0
5 / 16 = 0
6 / 1 = 6
6 / 2 = 3
6 / 4 = 1
6 / 8 = 0
6 / 16 = 0
7 / 1 = 7
7 / 2 = 3
7 / 4 = 1
7 / 8 = 0
7 / 16 = 0
8 / 1 = 8
8 / 2 = 4
8 / 4 = 2
8 / 8 = 1
8 / 16 = 0
9 / 1 = 9
9 / 2 = 4
9 / 4 = 2
9 / 8 = 1
9 / 16 = 0
10 / 1 = 10
10 / 2 = 5
10 / 4 = 2
10 / 8 = 1
10 / 16 = 0
```

@R.. rightfully reminds that the conversion from a `signed int` to an `unsigned int` can be done by adding 0u (unsigned 0).

And he also reminds that `un` can be returned directly instead of doing `memcpy()` to `n`. The conversion should be implementation-defined, but in 2's complement implementations of C, bit-for-bit copy is practically always the case.

Comment: Could you explain what `n >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)` in your `DivByShifting1` function does?

Comment: @AnishRam [Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift). It gives you 0 for n >= 0 and -1 for n < 0.

Comment: Personally, I would use the implementation-defined conversion from `unsigned` to `int` (taking place in the `return` statement) rather than `memcpy`...

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `/` operator:

```
int result = number / (1 << n);
```

Any decent compiler will compile this to the optimal bitshift with fixup for "rounding" of negative results.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to avoid explicit division in the source code.

Comment: Then I don't think it can be done portably, since `>>` is implementation-defined for negative operands. You'd at least need a way to condition the expression on whether the operand is negative...

Comment: Or it will use `idiv`; whichever is more efficient

Comment: You could cast the signed integer to unsigned and use the most significant bit as the sign bit value. I think, it'll still be doable, although significantly longer.

Comment: Yeah, just did added a version not relying on the implementation-defined behavior of `>>`.

Comment: I didn't see casts in the list of allowed operators. You could use `+0U` to convert to unsigned, but then there's no way to convert back without a cast or assignment...

Comment: Yep, I've thought of adding unsigned 0, but it's equivalent, so, not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should help you.

1) if your using `/` operator then the standard says (`ISO/IEC TR3 in 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators`)that the **result of the `/` operator** is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second.

2) if your using `>>` the standard says (`ISO/IEC TR3 in 6.5.7`) that **the result of `>>` where the LHS operand is a signed type and negative then the resulting value is `implementation defined`**.

so `/` will give you the result as you desired.

but `>>` on signed && negative number is dependant on your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the disassembly of `int div(int a){return a/4;}`:

```
leal 3(%rdi), %eax
testl %edi, %edi
cmovns %edi, %eax
sarl $2, %eax
```

one has to adjust the operand by `(1<<n)-1` if and only if the operand is negative.

An unconditional method would be to use `sgn(a)*(abs(a)>>n)`; both of which can be implemented with branchless bitmagic relying on the implementation defined behaviour.