# bitwise division by multiples of 2

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I found many posts about bitwise division and I completely understand most bitwise usage but I can't think of a specific division. I want to divide a given number (lets say 100) with all the multiples of 2 possible (ATTENTION: I don't want to divide with powers of 2 bit multiples!)
For example: 100/2, 100/4, 100/6, 100/8, 100/10...100/100
Also I know that because of using `unsigned int` the answers will be rounded for example 100/52=0 but it doesn't really matter, because I can both skip those answers or print them, no problem. My concern is mostly how I can divide with 6 or 10, etc. (multiples of 2). There is need for it to be done in C, because I can manage to transform any code you give me from Java to C.

Comment: Any indication why you want to do bit operations and not simply use divide?

Comment: This is the same as dividing the number by two, and then dividing the result by each possible integer.

Comment: You can't divide by multiples of two, only by powers of two, at least not easily.

Comment: i know its not dasblink as for you vaughn my friend dividing by 2 is just shifting right 1 bit dividing 4 is 2 bits shift dividing by 8 is 3 bits shift right but what about dividing by 6?....ALso my friend howard i want to do this because i have to do it for the uni...and i want to know if what the teacher asks is just fail or if it is possible to be done and how...

Comment: Checkout: [Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/315052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the math shown for the accepted solution to the [division by 3 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/315052), you can derive a recurrence for the division algorithm:

To compute `(int)`(X / Y)

- Let k be such that 2<sup>k</sup> ≥ Y and 2<sup>k-1</sup> < Y
  (note, 2<sup>k</sup> = `(1 << k)`)
- Let d = 2<sup>k</sup> - Y
- Then, if A = `(int)`(X / 2<sup>k</sup>) and B = X % 2<sup>k</sup>,

  ```
  X = (1 << k) * A + B
    = (1 << k) * A - Y * A + Y * A + B
    = d * A + Y * A + B
    = Y * A + (d * A + B)
  ```
- Thus,

  ```
  X/Y = A + (d * A + B)/Y
  ```

In otherwords,

> If `S(X, Y) := X/Y`, then `S(X, Y) := A + S(d * A + B, Y)`.

This recurrence can be implemented with a simple loop. The stopping condition for the loop is when the numerator falls below 2<sup>k</sup>. The function `divu` implements the recurrence, using only bitwise operators and using unsigned types. Helper functions for the math operations are left unimplemented, but shouldn't be too hard (the linked answer provides a full `add` implementation already). The `rs()` function is for "right-shift", which does sign extension on the `unsigned` input. The function `div` is the actual API for `int`, and checks for divide by zero and negative `y` before delegating to `divu`. `negate` does 2's complement negation.

```
static unsigned divu (unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned k = 0;
    unsigned pow2 = 0;
    unsigned mask = 0;
    unsigned diff = 0;
    unsigned sum = 0;
    while ((1 << k) < y) k = add(k, 1);
    pow2 = (1 << k);
    mask = sub(pow2, 1);
    diff = sub(pow2, y);
    while (x >= pow2) {
        sum = add(sum, rs(x, k));
        x = add(mul(diff, rs(x, k)), (x & mask));
    }
    if (x >= y) sum = add(sum, 1);
    return sum;
}

int div (int x, int y) {
    assert(y);
    if (y > 0) return divu(x, y);
    return negate(divu(x, negate(y)));
}
```

This implementation depends on `signed int` using 2's complement. For maximal portability, `div` should convert negative arguments to 2's complement before calling `divu`. Then, it should convert the result from `divu` back from 2's complement to the native signed representation.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for positive numbers. When the dividend or the divisor or both are negative, have flags to change the sign of the answer appropriately.

```
int divi(long long m, long long n)
{
    if(m==0 || n==0 || m<n)
        return 0;
    long long  a,b;
    int f=0;
    a=n;b=1;

    while(a<=m)
    {
        b = b<<1;
        a = a<<1;
        f=1;
    }

    if(f)
    {
        b = b>>1;
        a = a>>1;
    }

    b = b + divi(m-a,n);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the operator `/` for integer division as much as you can.

For instance, when you want to divide 100 by 6 or 10 you should write `100/6` or `100/10`.
When you mention bit wise division do you (1) mean an implementation of operator `/` or (2)  you are referring to the division by a power of two number.

For (1) a processor should have an integer division unit. If not the compiler should provide a good implementation.

For (2) you can use `100>>2` instead of `100/4`. If the numerator is known at compile time then a good compiler should automatically use the shift instruction.