# Division by 3 without division operator

Tags: c, numbers

I was given this question in an interview to describe the output in comments.

```
unsigned int d2(unsigned int a)
{
__int64 q = (__int64)a * 0x0AAAAAAAB;  // (2^33+1) / 3
return (unsigned int)(q >> 33);
}
```

I have checked other questions in Stackoverflow related to division by 3 but none seems so fast and small.
Can anybody help me in explaining how the function is giving the output written in comments ?

Comment: Must have something to do with overflow.

Comment: It is the binary equivalent of taking a number, multiplying it by 100000/3 which is about 33333, and then dividing by 100000, leaving it approximately equal to the original number divided by 3.

Comment: Odd question for an interview :)

Comment: Eg: 66 * 33334 = 2200044, then shift the decimal point over, = 22.00044. Or, 22. We use 33334 so the number rounds up, otherwise you'd get 21.998... which truncates to 21.

Comment: @CoryNelson: not really. It's not, as the OP believes, a C thing though: it's a very common compiler optimisation. Perhaps the interview was for a Reverse Engineering job.

Comment: [Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function divides a 32-bit unsigned number by 3.

If you multiply by 2^33 and then divide by 2^33 (by right shifting), then you get the original number. But if you multiply by (2^33)/3 and then divide by 2^33, you effectively divide by three.

The last digit is `B` instead of `A` to cause the result to be rounded up.

There is no need to actually write this in your code because the compiler will usually do this for you. [Try it and see.](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22int%20div3%28%20int%20i%20%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20i%20/%203;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/opt/intel/bin/icc%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O3%20-march=native%20-std=c++11%20%22%7D%5D%7D) (Furthermore, for a signed input, the compiler can safely generate a signed right shift, but the C language does not define such an operation.)

Comment: q >> 33 is divided by 2^33, but how 0x0AAAAAAAB is 2^33/3 ??

Comment: @Learner That's what it is… it's just a number. It's rounded up from the exact fraction.

Comment: There must be a way the number has come up. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Learner Yes, by dividing 2^33 by 3 and rounding up. There's not more to it than that. One-third happens to be a repeating fraction, 0.AAAAA… in hexadecimal, just as it is 0.33333… in decimal, because neither 16^n nor 10^n is divisible by 3 for any n.

Comment: @Potatoswater: Thanks for explanations. I got one another way to derive this. I am thinking like this: if I multiply 0x55555555 with 3 it gives -1. and the 2's complement of 0x55555555 is 0xAAAAAAAB. And 0xAAAAAAAB is approx ~ 2^33/3.