# How to traverse a 2D array in zigzag order

Tags: c++, arrays, zigzag

We have an `int` 2D array as follow:

```
int matrix[4][4] =
{{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8}
{9,10,11,12}
{13,14,15,16}};
```

By convention if we wants to print out the array by order we can:

```
    for (int x=0; x<4; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<4; y++) 
        {                                        
            cout << matrix[x][y] << "  ";
        }   
        cout << endl;               
    }
```

**Output:**

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

**My question is:** How can we traverse the 2D array in zigzag order. For example, print out the array values as such:

```
 1  2  3  4  
 8  7  6  5
 9 10 11 12
16 15 14 13
```

Comment: If you vote this down, kindly leave a comment here why u do so. So I can improve next time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What other information do you need from this question? This question is as straight forward as you see here.

Comment: You are expected to show some efforts of your own here, what you have tried etc. So isn't a _Gimme teh codez plz!_ service.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But I have seen nemerous questions in SO which accumulated over 500 positive votes without even stating what they had done. Some questions are as simple as one line. One of the numerous example is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694546/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators

Comment: I am ok for anyone to vote down my questions if I really asked an open ended or duplicated bad question. But please don't vote my questions down blindly.

Comment: _'... One of the numerous example is ...'_ If you convince anyone that your question will be adopted by the community wiki, but as it looks I doubt so ...

Comment: +1, for fighting back :-)

Comment: Is Morton Code aka Z-Curve a solution to you?

Comment: Please unhold this question. It has been reworded.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
bool r=false;
for (int x=0; x<4; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y<4; y++)
    {
        cout << matrix[x][r ? 3-y : y] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    r = !r;
}
```

Comment: I think that the ? counts as an if() instruction.  But let the OP decide.  Before the OP edited the question, the instructions were to not use if() in the solution.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh, I never saw that constraint. And I tried to have minimal changes compared to the code of the question, so it's not necessarily efficient, elegant or anything.

Comment: Gave you +1 anyway.  Don't see it in the OP's post now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (before you edited the original question, you asked for a solution to the original problem without using if() or conditionals):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int matrix[4][4] =
        {{1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16}};

    bool backwards = false;        
    int incre = 1;
    for (int x=0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        int index = 3 * backwards;
        for (int y=0; y<4; y++, index += incre) 
            cout << matrix[x][index] << "  ";
        incre = -incre;
        backwards = !backwards;
        cout << endl;               
    }
}
```

The trick is that you want the column count to increase one row, decrease on the next row, etc.  That's the reason for the incre variable.

The "backwards" is just a boolean that tells us if we're going backwards or forwards, thus setting up the proper index to start from.

Comment: + 1 for you. I was looking for a solution something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a single `for`-loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int matrix[][4] = { { 0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, {12,13,14,15}};

int main() {
  for (int x=0; x<16; x++) {
    cout << matrix[x/4][ x%4 * ((x/4+1)&1) + (3-x%4)*((x/4)&1) ] << "  ";
    if (x%4==3) cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The first `[]` simply gives you the row by dividing by 4 -> `i/4`.
The second `[]` gives the column in 2 steps. It takes the reminder after dividing by 4 -> `x%4` and multiplies by 1 if it's an even row -> `(x/4+1)&1` then adds the reminder in reverse order -> `3-x%4` multiplied by 1 if it's an odd row -> `(x/4)&1`

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and easily understandable approach

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int matrix[4][4] = { { 0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, {12,13,14,15}};
    bool forward = true;
    int j;
    for(int i = 0,k=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(forward)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
            forward = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=3;j>=0;j--)
            {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
            forward = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```