# Trying to multiply a number from 0..4096 by 0.3 using only integer math

Tags: c, integer, scaling

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I'd multiply a number from 0..4096 by 0.3 using  just integers with shift operations and scaling, **without dividing**, in C. I'm new to this stuff and any input or step by step suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I think he means any given number from the range `[0, 4096]` multiplied by 0.3

Comment: Well, first you need to start learning how floating point numbers work behind the scenes. In your case, `0.3 = 3/10`, so you first need to multiply by 3, then divide by 10, all using integers.

Comment: I do mean from the range 0...4096. The idea is to scale up so both are integers and thereby avoid floating point operations.

Comment: Multiply by 3 and then divide by 10.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694546/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators

Comment: I understand that the decimal parts of a float are 2^-1, 2^-2, 2^-3, 2^-4 etc.

Comment: (a*9830 + 16384)>>15

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I upvoted your comment then noticed *'without dividing in C'*.

Comment: I hope by "scaling" you meant "multiplication", since that's what most of the answers assume.

Comment: @abligh I upvoted his answer then noticed your comment, and *then* noticed '_without dividing in C_'.

Comment: @KenWhite. going to floating point doesn't do anything to solve the problem of 0.3 not being able to be represented precisely.  anything that can be done with finite-precision floating-point binary numbers can also be done with fixed-point binary numbers.  just follow the same rules.

Comment: What's the format of the numbers? Fixed-point? Floating-point? Fixed-point decimal?

Answer (score 23):

Multiplying by 0.3 is the same as multiplying by `(0.3*2^n)`, then dividing by `2^n`. The second stage is equivalent to a shift right of `n`.

But what's the *best* value of `n`?

To find this, take your largest integer and find the largest value of `n` such that you can multiply by `(0.3*2^n)` without an overflow. With 64 bit unsigned integers and 4096 as the maximum value, you need

```
0.3*2^n <= 2^(64-12)
```

or

```
0.3 <= 2^(64-12-n)
```

That inequality has maximum `n` when the RHS is equal to 0.5, so

```
2^-1 = 2^(64-12-n)
```

so `-1 = 64-12-n`, `n = 64-12+1 = 53`.

So the answer is multiply by `2^53*0.3` then shift right by 53, i.e.

```
/* designed to work with input values 0 .. 4096 only */
uint64_t
multiplyby0_3 (uint64_t x)
{
    return (x * 2702159776422297ULL) >> 53;
}
```

To check that doesn't overflow and we've got the best `n`, from `bc`:

```
2702159776422297*4096 = 11068046444225728512
2^64                  = 18446744073709551616
```

IE it won't overflow, but if we multiplied it by 2 again, it would.

For 32 bit integers, the answer is multiply by `2^21*0.3` then shift right by 21, i.e.

```
/* designed to work with input values 0 .. 4096 only */
uint32_t
multiplyby0_3 (uint32_t x)
{
    return (x * 629146U) >> 21;
}
```

And finally, you can decompose any multiply into a number of additions by looking at the binary `1`'s in the multiplier. So you permit *'scaling'* and I assumed that meant multiply. If not, here is the 32 bit version (64 bit version left as an exercise for the reader) exploiting the fact that `629146` is `10011001100110011010` (a neat pattern due to the recurring binary fraction). We'll round the other way and use `10011001100110011001` instead.

```
/* designed to work with input values 0 .. 4096 only */
uint32_t
multiplyby0_3 (uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t y;
    x += x<<3;    /* * 1001 */
    y = x<<4 + x; /* * 10011001 */
    y += y<<8;    /* * 1001100110011001 */
    y += x<<16;   /* * 10011001100110011001 */
    return y >> 21;
}
```

Comment: Using that many bits is overkill - since the input range is only ~ 12 bits then you should be able to do this with full accuracy well within a 32 bit intermediate value.

Comment: @duskwuff I don't think that's right. The highest value possible (**given the input is limited to 0 .. 4096**) is 4096, so the bit in the brackets is at most ``2702159776422297 * 4096 = 11068046444225728512` which fits comfortably (just) into 64 bits. I'll stick a comment on the code samples.

Comment: @PaulR isn't that what the 32 bit example does? Yes, I realise it's overkill but I wanted to teach OP how to work it out in the general case. Proving a lower number of bits will never give a different answer is more work in any case!

Comment: Sure - if you change `629146ULL` to `629146U` so that you're only using 32 bit arithmetic then it's fine.

Comment: @abligh gets the up arrow.  the number of bits to commit to 0.3 is the number of bits in your unsigned word (64 or 32) minus 12 (since 2^12 = 4096).  so you want 0.3 to be represented as 0.3 * 2^52 or 0.3 * 2^20, multiply your value, and (for rounding to nearest) add either 2^51 and shift right 52 bits or add 2^19 and shift right by 20 bits.

Answer (score 8):

If you have fast integer multiplication, but you don't have integer division, you can get a reasonable approximation by multiplying by 1229, then shifting right by 12 bits. For instance:

```
>> 100 * 1229
122900
>> 122900 >> 12
30
```

This works because 1229 is about `0.3 * 1 << 12`. The "real" value is 1228.8, so the estimate will be high by 1 in some cases (68 out of 4097 values). It will never be off by more than 1, though.

Comment: I'd do a +2048 before >>12 to do a simple rounding.

Comment: What if the multiplication overflows?

Comment: @EOF: 122900 is only 17 bits, so with 32 bit ints and a 12 bit input range this should be fine.

Comment: @EOF The maximum intermediate result, given the range specified in the question, is `1229 * 4096 = 5033984`. That's well within the range of a 32-bit integer; if you need to stay within 16 bits, that's a bit tougher.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't appear to be accurate for all input values. I took it that OP was trying to find a way of producing the same thing as multiplying an integer by 0.3 (rounding the result), and this would appear to get it wrong occasionally. You need a few more bits (possibly not as many as in my answer!)

Comment: @abligh It's pretty accurate… There's no number between 0 and 4096 for which `(x * 1229) >> 12` differs from `x * 0.3` by more than 0.9.

Answer (score 6):

Using a classic hack for `divu10()` below.  I prefer the *n and shift approach, but thought I offer another POV.

```
unsigned mult3tenths(unsigned x) {
  return divu10(x*3);
}

unsigned divu10(unsigned n) {
  unsigned q, rem;
  q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
  q = q + (q >> 4);
  q = q + (q >> 8);
  q = q + (q >> 16);
  q = q >> 3;
  rem = n - q*10;
  return q + ((rem + 6) >> 4);  
}
```

Comment: neat, though I'm saddened the second line didn't read `div10(x+(x<<1))` and later  `rem=n-(q<<3)-(q<<1)` just to eliminate all multiplication as well :-)

Comment: @abligh Suspect a good compiler will take `x*3` or `x+(x<<1)` and make the same code.

Comment: yeah it will indeed. But for a laugh, I found an even shorter way without explicit multiplication and added it to my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is not a coding example, sorry about that, but if the set is so small (range [0;4096]), why not create a block of results and use a pointer to extract values? It will greatly reduce the GPU cycles, since there are not memory restrictions.

Comment: GPU cycles? memory restrictions?

Comment: Yeah... It slips from my mind.... That integer restriction makes me think at GPU computing, ATI chips and bitcoin mining... My mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply tried a lot of combinations of the form `(A*x + B) >> n` with the below test code and came up with:

```
// Scale by 4915, then shift 14.
int Mult3Tenths(int x) {
  return (x*4915 + 0) >> 14;  // Use 4915L if `int` is 16 bit.
}
```

Test code

```
#define N3 (4096)
int main(void) {
  int target[N3 + 1];
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i <= N3; i++) {
    target[i] = 0.3 * i;
  }

  // form (A*x + B) >> n
  int A, B, n;
  int besti = 0;
  for (n = 0; n < 31; n++) {
    int Amin = ((N3 * 0.3 - 1) * (1 << n) - (1 << n)) / N3 - 1;
    int Amax = ((N3 * 0.3 + 1) * (1 << n) + (1 << n)) / N3 + 1;
    for (A = Amin; A <= Amax; A++) {
      int Bmax = 1 << n;
      for (B = -Bmax; B <= Bmax; B++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= N3; i++) {
          int y = (A * i + B) >> n;
          if (y != target[i])
            break;
          if (i > besti) {
            besti = i;
            if (i == N3) {
              printf("i:%i A:%d B:%d n:%d\n", i, A, B, n);
              printf("!!!\n");
              exit(0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("???\n");
  return 0;
}
```