# Divide by 9 without using division or multiplication operator

Tags: c, algorithm, math, multiplication, integer-division

This question I have tried to solve it but couldn't get any way. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regular subtraction way of doing division is not the intention here, ingenious way of using shifting operator to get this done is the intention.

Comment: The simplest way to do division is by repeated subtraction.

Comment: Martin James: no it it not homework but rather http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/makemytrip-interview-questions-set-6/ this question.

Comment: I wonder why people are in a hurry to down vote to get more up votes for themselves.

Comment: @newbie_old it wasn't me, but downvoting costs the down-voter. It doesn't gain them points.

Comment: @newbie_old I've posted a belated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution heavily inspired by [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) that really uses only bit shifts:

```
def divu9(n):
    q = n - (n >> 3)
    q = q + (q >> 6)
    q = q + (q>>12) + (q>>24); q = q >> 3
    r = n - (((q << 2) << 1) + q)
    return q + ((r + 7) >> 4)
    #return q + (r > 8)
```

Comment: Check the link I provided. The chapter is downloadable for free and worth the read.

Answer (score 3):

Although an answer has been accepted, I post mine for what it's worth.

**UPDATE**. This works by multiplying by a recurring binary fraction. In decimal 1/9 = 0.1111111 recurring. In binary, that is 1/1001 = 0.000111000111000111 recurring.

Notice the binary multiplier is in groups of 6 bits, decimal 7 recurring. So what I want to do here, is to multiply the dividend by 7, shift it right 6 bits, and add it to a running quotient. However to keep significance, I do the shift *after* the addition, and shift the quotient `q` after the loop ends to align it properly.

There are up to 6 iterations of the calculation loop for a 32 bit `int` (6 bits * 6 shifts = 36 bits).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x, y, q, d;
    int i, err = 0;

    for (x=1; x<100; x++) {             // candidates
        q = 0;                          // quotient
        y = (x << 3) - x;               // y = x * 7

        while(y) {                      // until nothing significant
            q += y;                     // add (effectively) binary 0.000111
            y >>= 6;                    // realign
        }
        q >>= 6;                        // align

        d  = x / 9;                     // the true answer
        if (d != q) {
            printf ("%d / 9 = %d (%d)\n", x, q, d);     // print any errors
            err++;
        }
    }

    printf ("Errors: %d\n", err);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails for every candidate that is a multiple of 9, for rounding error, due to the same reason that multiplying decimal 27 * 0.111111 = 2.999999 and not 3. So I now complicate the answer by keeping the 4 l.s. bits of the quotient for rounding. The result is it works for all `int` values limited by the two top nibbles, one for the `* 7` and one for the `* 16` significance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x, y, q, d;
    int i, err = 0;

    for (x=1; x<0x00FFFFFF; x++) {
        q = 8;                          // quotient with (effectively) 0.5 for rounding
        y = (x << 3) - x;               // y = x * 7
        y <<= 4;                        // y *= 16 for rounding

        while(y) {                      // until nothing significant
            q += y;                     // add (effectively) binary 0.000111
            y >>= 6;                    // realign
        }
        q >>= (4 + 6);                  // the 4 bits significance + recurrence

        d  = x / 9;                     // the true answer
        if (d != q) {
            printf ("%d / 9 = %d (%d)\n", x, q, d);     // print any errors
            err++;
        }
    }

    printf ("Errors: %d\n", err);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In binary, that is 1/1001 = 0.000111000111000111 recurring. Didn't get this. Oh got it. Basically 1/9 is 1/1001.

Comment: The first binary after the `.` represents one-half, the next one-quarter, etc. So that's 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 + etc. Those first 6 bits (after the point) equal 0.109375 decimal, so you can see it is converging on 0.111111 recurring decimal.

Comment: Great logic. I think i<6 is because 6*6 is 36 and more than 32 so you take care of all 32 bit numbers. But why not x*7 and shifting by 6 so the code should be 
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {           // 6 shifts of 6 bits = 36 bit shift
            y >>= 6;                    // realign
            z += y;                     // add (effectively) binary 0.000111
        }
May i also know why is this added "z >>= 6;                        // align" ?

Comment: @newbie_old thank you. Two points 1) instead of the `for(i ...) {` loop it would be cleaner with `while(y) {`, since when `y` has been shifted to `0` there is no point in continuing. 2) The reason for `z >>= 6;` after the loop is because the two instructions within the loop should have been the other way round: shift `y` before adding to `z`. I did it this way to keep significance.

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by "to keep significance" ?

Comment: Example 2 is working with a fixed format `point` with 28 integral bits and 4 fractional bits. The quotient started with a value of 8, which here represents one-half (in binary 0.1000), so as to round the final quotient when it is finally divided by 16.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694778/4907651

Exactly what you're looking for except the divisor is 3.

**EDIT: explanation**

I will replace the `add` function with simply `+` as you're looking for the solution without using `*` or `/` only.

*In this explanation, we assume we are dividing by 3*.

Also, I am assuming you know how to convert decimal to binary and vice versa.

```
int divideby3 (int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 3) {
        sum += (num >> 2);
        num = (num >> 2) + (num & 3);
    }
    if (num == 3)
        sum += 1;
    return sum; 
}
```

This approach uses bitwise operators:

- bitwise AND: `&`.
- bitwise left shift: `<<`. Shifts binary values left.
- bitwise right shift: `>>`. Shifts binary values right.
- bitwise XOR: `^`

The first condition `(num > 3)` is as such because the divisor is 3. In your case, the divisor is 9, so when you use it, the condition must be `(num > 9)`.

**Suppose the number we want to divide is 6.**

In binary, 6 is represented as `000110`.

Now, we enter `while (num > 3)` loop. The first statement adds `sum` (initialised to 0) to `num >> 2`.

**What `num >> 2` does:**

> num in binary initially: `00000000 00000110`
>
> after bitwise shift: `00000000 00000001   i.e. 1 in decimal`

`sum` after adding `num >> 2` is `1`.

Since we know `num >> 2` is equal to 1, we add that to `num & 3`.

> num in binary initially: `00000000 00000110`
>
> 3 in binary: `00000000 00000011`

*For each bit position in the result of expression `a & b`, the bit is 1 if both operands contain 1, and 0 otherwise*

> result of `num & 3`: `00000000 00000010   i.e. 2 in decimal`

`num` after `num = (num >> 2) + (num & 3)` equals `1 + 2` = `3`

**Now, since `num` is EQUAL to 3, we enter `if (num==3)` loop.**

We then add 1 to sum, and return the value. This value of `sum` is the quotient.

As expected, the value returned is 2.

Hope that wasn't a horrible explanation.

Comment: Then repeat --> divide by 9.

Comment: I didn't understand the explanation. I have read 100 times already, if you can explain it I can put this as correct answer.

Comment: @newbie_old here is an explanation. Please let me know if I wasn't very clear explaining. I will elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop and every step you should substract `N-9 ..` then `(N-9)-9` .. until `N<9 OR N=0` and every substraction you count the step For exemple : `36/9 36-9=27 cmpt (1) 27-9=18 cmpt(2) 18-9=9 cmpt(3) 9-9=0 cmpt (4)`

So `36/9= 4`

Answer (score 0):

This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication algorithm can do it using only subtraction and binary shifts in log(n) time. However, as far as I know, state-of-the-art hardware already either use this one, or even better algorithms. Therefore, I do not think there is anything you can do (assuming performance is your goal) unless you can somehow avoid the division completely or change your use case so that you can divide by a power of 2, because there are some tricks for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to divide a positive number, you can use the following function:

```
unsigned int divideBy9(unsigned int num) 
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    while (num >= 9)
    {
        result += 1;
        num -= 9;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the case of a negative number, you can use a similar approach.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to multiply/divide, you're left with addition/subtraction. Dividing by a number shows how many times the divisor contains the dividend. You can use this in return: How many times can you subtract the number from the original value?

```
divisor = 85;
dividend = 9;
remaining = divisor;
result = 0;
while (remaining >= dividend)
{
    remaining -= dividend;
    result++;
}
std::cout << divisor << " / " << dividend << " = " << result;
```