# Where does this value come from in this Sudoku solver implementation in MIPS asm

Tags: assembly, mips, sudoku

I'm interested in this block of code, from https://github.com/delucas/sudoku-project/blob/master/sudoku-assembler-mips/sudokiller.s#L158

```
# 3x3-Box check
div     $t0, $a1, 3           # $t0 = row / 3
mul     $t0, $t0, 27          # Offset of the row  ->>> Where does the 27 come from?
div     $t1, $a2, 3           # $t1 = col / 3
mul     $t1, $t1, 3           # Offset of the column
add     $t1, $t0, $t1         # Offset of the first cell in the box
```

I'm trying to understand what we're doing here, but I'm confused on what the significance of the number 27 is.

Comment: You can divide by 3 [with a multiply and a right-shift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/171369/224132).  That will faster than `div` on most machines.

Comment: @PeterCordes At the expense of some readability, of course

Comment: @qwr: you should be able to wrap it into an assembler macro, for readability.  Besides, that's what comments are for in asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board is a two-dimensional array, so for example `board[2][2]` gets translated to `board[2*9+2]`. The code for row is equivalent to `(t0/3)*27` which aligns the row number to (the first number of) its box and then effectively multiplies by 9, indexing the row properly.

Comment: How would this differ if we were checking a box of size 3x2 (2 rows, 3 cols). For a 6x6 board.

Comment: @TalenKylon Well first, assuming it's numbered row by row, you align to the corner of the box (there are 2 boxes) and then multiply to get the board size `(t0/2)*12`